# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode, beautifulsoup, python-2.x, python-unicode

I'm having problems dealing with unicode characters from text fetched from different web pages (on different sites). I am using BeautifulSoup.

The problem is that the error is not always reproducible; it sometimes works with some pages, and sometimes, it barfs by throwing a `UnicodeEncodeError`. I have tried just about everything I can think of, and yet I have not found anything that works consistently without throwing some kind of Unicode-related error.

One of the sections of code that is causing problems is shown below:

```
agent_telno = agent.find('div', 'agent_contact_number')
agent_telno = '' if agent_telno is None else agent_telno.contents[0]
p.agent_info = str(agent_contact + ' ' + agent_telno).strip()
```

Here is a stack trace produced on SOME strings when the snippet above is run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foobar.py", line 792, in <module>
    p.agent_info = str(agent_contact + ' ' + agent_telno).strip()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I suspect that this is because some pages (or more specifically, pages from some of the sites) may be encoded, whilst others may be unencoded. All the sites are based in the UK and provide data meant for UK consumption - so there are no issues relating to internalization or dealing with text written in anything other than English.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to solve this so that I can CONSISTENTLY fix this problem?

Comment: If you're getting these errors as a user rather than as a developer, check https://serverfault.com/questions/54591/how-to-install-change-locale-on-debian and https://askubuntu.com/questions/599808/cannot-set-lc-ctype-to-default-locale-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I'll add this point don't use https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter for this stuff. Was using that interpreter to trial stuff out and it's not configured correctly for Unicode! Was always printing in a format 'B'\nnn''... when all I wanted was a guillemet! Tried on a VM and it worked immediately as expected using chr()

Comment: Try this `import os; import locale;  os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"; myLocale=locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL, locale="en_GB.UTF-8"); ... print(myText.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))`.

Comment: @hhh I ran your snippet NameError: name 'myText' is not defined

Comment: Try to set [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) in the shell, before executing your script: `$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8`

Comment: it my case the string was - u'1d6f4975842f050bf6503b19250d09f997b34f4a\n' , I just used `.encode('utf-8').strip()` over the same string. What is does is - it remove the last `\n` from the string which was creating the problem before, even after used encode('utf-8') before.

Answer (score 1521, accepted):

Read the Python [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html). This error is the [very first example](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type).

Do not use `str()` to convert from unicode to encoded text / bytes.

Instead, use [`.encode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to encode the string:

```
p.agent_info = u' '.join((agent_contact, agent_telno)).encode('utf-8').strip()
```

or work entirely in unicode.

Comment: agreed! a good rule of thumb I was taught is to use the "unicode sandwich" idea. Your script accepts bytes from the outside world, but all processing should be done in unicode. Only when you are ready to output your data should it be mushed back into bytes!

Comment: In case someone else gets confused by this, I found a strange thing: my terminal uses utf-8, and when I `print` my utf-8 strings it works nicely. However when I pipe my programs output to a file, it throws a `UnicodeEncodeError`. In fact, when output is redirected (to a file or a pipe), I find that `sys.stdout.encoding` is `None`! Tacking on `.encode('utf-8')` solves the problem.

Comment: @drevicko: use `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` instead i.e., print Unicode strings and let the environment to set the expected encoding.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Do you think that's a valid approach in every case? Let's say you have a tool that's exporting a report which needs to have a particular encoding, it seems less straightforward to me that the user would need to change the environment settings just for that one export. Then I would rather have the program take the encoding as a parameter with a sensible default.

Comment: @steinar: nothing is valid in every case. In general, a user shouldn't care that you use Python to implement your utility (the interface shouldn't change if you decide to reimplement it in another language for whatever reason) and therefore you should not expect that user even aware about python-specific envvars. It is bad UI to force user to specify character encoding; embed the character encoding in the report format if necessary. Note: no hardcoded encoding can be "sensible default" in the general case.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I agree that this varies by use case. My concern was that readers might follow the pattern of setting the environment variable rather than having it more clearly configurable, leading to users having to worry about in what language the utility was/will be written. I think having users specify the character encoding can make a lot of sense in some cases and seems then to be a better alternative than setting environment variables. But then I'm thinking of tools for advanced users.

Comment: `PYTHONIOENCODING` seems to be required if the locale is incorrectly built or the user is using a non-UTF-8 locale. Check `locale` before setting `PYTHONIOENCODING`

Comment: This is bad and confusing advice. The reason people use str is because the object IS NOT already a string, so there's no `.encode()` method to call.

Comment: @Cerin I'm not sure what you mean. If you're getting this error, you definitely have an object of type `str` -- a string.

Comment: @agf, Nope, this error was being thrown by this code, `unicode(list(DjangoQueryObject))`

Comment: What is the reason for the .strip()? Is that recommended for all conversion calls to .encode('utf-8')?

Comment: @Praxiteles No, it's not. It was just copied from the original code, like the join and the variable names. It's something specific to his use case.

Comment: @drevicko right on that is totally what is happening

Comment: I perused the docs you referenced, but still don't understand why both `u''` and `.encode('utf-8')` are necessary.  Doesn't the "u" indicate a unicode string?

Comment: @Matt I'm not sure I understand your question. Yes, "u" indicates a unicode string. The `encode` takes the decoded unicode string and encodes it into a specific utf-8 byte sequence. So after encoding it as utf-8, it's just a sequence of bytes, not unicode any more, as far as Python is concerned.

Comment: @agf It was that one is a unicode string and the other is a byte sequence that I wasn't appreciating.  I still don't understand why piping in the shell breaks without the `encode()` call (per @drevicko's comment.)

Comment: I use Mojibake (https://github.com/BeetleChunks/Mojibake) in my projects for managing data encodings. It has some useful functions for encoding/decoding strings and unicode as well as dicts, tuples, and lists. Its a good reference for how to encode/decode various data types too.

Comment: i get the following error:  Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

Comment: @nomaam Then either you need to explicitly call `decode` to turn the bytes into a string, or you've got `decode` where you need `encode` or `encode` where you need `decode`.

Answer (score 487):

This is a classic python unicode pain point! Consider the following:

```
a = u'bats\u00E0'
print a
 => batsà
```

All good so far, but if we call str(a), let's see what happens:

```
str(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Oh dip, that's not gonna do anyone any good! To fix the error, encode the bytes explicitly with .encode and tell python what codec to use:

```
a.encode('utf-8')
 => 'bats\xc3\xa0'
print a.encode('utf-8')
 => batsà
```

Voil\u00E0!

The issue is that when you call str(), python uses the default character encoding to try and encode the bytes you gave it, which in your case are sometimes representations of unicode characters. To fix the problem, you have to tell python how to deal with the string you give it by using .encode('whatever_unicode'). Most of the time, you should be fine using utf-8.

For an excellent exposition on this topic, see Ned Batchelder's PyCon talk here: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: Personal note:  When trying to type ".encode" don't accidentally type ".unicode" then wonder why nothing is working.

Comment: Good advice. But what do you do instead when you were using str(x) to print objects that may or may not be strings? str(x) works if x is a number, date time, boolean, or normal string. Suddenly if its a unicode it stops working. Is there a way to get the same behaviour or do we now need to add an IF check to test if the object is string to use .encode, and str() otherwise?

Comment: Same question could be asked with `None` value.

Answer (score 253):

I found elegant work around for me to remove symbols and continue to keep string as string in follows:

```
yourstring = yourstring.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
```

It's important to notice that using the ignore option is **dangerous** because it silently drops any unicode(and internationalization) support from the code that uses it, as seen here (convert unicode):

```
>>> u'City: Malmö'.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
'City: Malm'
```

Comment: You made my day! For utf-8, it's sufficient to do: `yourstring = yourstring.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: for me this did work but my case was different, i was saving file names and was having "/" in the name and the path didn't existed so I have to use .replace("/","") and thus saved mine script. while ignoring the ascii also works for 'utf-8' case also.

Comment: @harrypotter0 for concatenating file paths correctly use `os.path.join()`, it's a very good habit when you start doing cross-platform programming. :)

Answer (score 191):

well i tried everything but it did not help, after googling around i figured the following and it helped.
python 2.7 is in use.

```
# encoding=utf8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: Don't do this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script, although when you have answers like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31137935/2141635 near the top of the results when you search for the error I can see why it may seem like a good idea.

Comment: I tried almost all of the suggestions in this topic and really none worked for me. Finally I tried this one. And it's really THE ONLY one what worked simple and good.   If someone say  "Don't do this, then come with a simple Solution. Otherwise use this one. Because it's a good working copy and past solution.

Comment: This solution works with file.write(), as well as print().

Comment: How could this be done in python3 ? Would be happy to know.

Comment: Don't do this! If you do this, you can avoid *heaps* of arcane knowledge of Python2 and unicode! The horror!

Comment: I'd just add an `if sys.version_info.major < 3:`

Comment: I agree. I use            import sys
import io
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.detach(), encoding = 'utf-8')

Comment: Confirmed for my Python 2.6, 2.7 versions. Tried other solutions but those won't work. Only this one.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it changes the encoding for all of Python, which means that external modules, which could perhaps have been written with the assumption that ASCII is the default encoding, are now operating with a different encoding.  I am not brave enough to risk chasing bugs in all the external modules that my particular application uses.  So if it's working for you, it may be only because you're not using an external module that is fragile in this way.

Answer (score 107):

A subtle problem causing even print to fail is having your environment variables set wrong, eg. here LC_ALL set to "C".  In Debian they discourage setting it: [Debian wiki on Locale](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale)

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.utf8
$ echo $LC_ALL 
C
$ python -c "print (u'voil\u00e0')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
$ export LC_ALL='en_US.utf8'
$ python -c "print (u'voil\u00e0')"
voilà
$ unset LC_ALL
$ python -c "print (u'voil\u00e0')"
voilà
```

Comment: Got exactly same issue, so bad I didn't checked it before [reporting](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/244). Thanks a lot. By the way, you can replace first two commands with `env|grep -E '(LC|LANG)'`.

Comment: Just my two cents on wrong encoding issue. I frequently use `mc` in "subshell mode" (`Ctrl-O`) and I also forgot that I added the following alias to bash: `alias mc="LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 mc"`. So when I tried to run poorly-written scripts which rely on `ru_RU.UTF-8` internally, they just die. Tried lots of stuff from this thread before I discovered the real issue. :)

Comment: YOU ARE AWESOME. In GSUTIL, my rsync was failing because of exactly this problem. Fixed the LC_ALL and everything works fine as wine. <3 THANK YOU <3

Answer (score 41):

The problem is that you're trying to print a unicode character, but your terminal doesn't support it.

You can try installing `language-pack-en` package to fix that:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en
```

which provides English translation data updates for all supported packages (including Python). Install different language package if necessary (depending which characters you're trying to print).

On some Linux distributions it's required in order to make sure that the default English locales are set-up properly (so unicode characters can be handled by shell/terminal). Sometimes it's easier to install it, than configuring it manually.

Then when writing the code, make sure you use the right encoding in your code.

For example:

```
open(foo, encoding='utf-8')
```

If you've still a problem, double check your system configuration, such as:

- Your locale file (`/etc/default/locale`), which should have e.g.

  ```
  LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
  LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
  ```

  or:

  ```
  LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
  LANG=C.UTF-8
  ```
- Value of `LANG`/[`LC_CTYPE`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3219/21471) in shell.
- Check which locale your shell supports by:

  ```
  locale -a | grep "UTF-8"
  ```

---

Demonstrating the problem and solution in fresh VM.

1. Initialize and provision the VM (e.g. using [`vagrant`](https://www.vagrantup.com/)):

   ```
   vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64; vagrant up; vagrant ssh
   ```

   <sup>See: [available Ubuntu boxes](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu).</sup>.
2. Printing unicode characters (such as trade mark sign like `™`):

   ```
   $ python -c 'print(u"\u2122");'
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
   UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2122' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
   ```
3. Now installing `language-pack-en`:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get -y install language-pack-en
   The following extra packages will be installed:
     language-pack-en-base
   Generating locales...
     en_GB.UTF-8... /usr/sbin/locale-gen: done
   Generation complete.
   ```
4. Now problem should be solved:

   ```
   $ python -c 'print(u"\u2122");'
   ™
   ```
5. Otherwise, try the following command:

   ```
   $ LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 python -c 'print(u"\u2122");'
   ™
   ```

Comment: What has `language-pack-en` got to do with Python or this question? AFAIK, it may provide language translations to messages but has nothing to do with encoding

Comment: On some Linux distributions it's required in order to make sure that the default English locales are set-up properly, especially when running Python script on the Terminal. It worked for me at one point. See: [character encoding](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3218/21471)

Comment: Ah, ok. You mean if you want to use a non-English locale? I guess the user will also have to edit `/etc/locale.gen` to ensure their locale is built before using it?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Added reproducible steps of the problem in VM to make it clearer. I've tested and the solution still works.

Comment: Great update @kenorb! Instead of installing `language-pack-en`, what would've happened if you just uncommented `en_GB.UTF-8` in `/etc/locale.gen` and ran `locale-gen`? Also, what was the result of `locale` before making changes. The reason I ask is that I'm intrigued what `language-pack-en` actually does :)

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Commented out `LANG` from `/etc/default/locale` (as `/etc/locale.gen` does't exist) and ran `locale-gen`, but it didn't help. I'm not sure what `language-pack-en` exactly does, as I didn't find much documentation and listing the content of it doesn't help much.

Comment: it is unlikely that there are no utf-8 locales on a desktop system already i.e., it is likely that you don't need to install anything, just configure `LANG`/ `LC_CTYPE`/ `LC_ALL` instead (e.g., `LANG=C.UTF-8`).

Answer (score 33):

In shell:

1. Find supported UTF-8 locale by the following command:

   ```
   locale -a | grep "UTF-8"
   ```
2. Export it, before running the script, e.g.:

   ```
   export LC_ALL=$(locale -a | grep UTF-8)
   ```

   or manually like:

   ```
   export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
   ```
3. Test it by printing special character, e.g. `™`:

   ```
   python -c 'print(u"\u2122");'
   ```

Above tested in Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes this is the best short answer, we cannot modify the source code to use .encode

Comment: I used it in python3 and its working fine now after setting LC_ALL. Thanks

Answer (score 30):

I've actually found that in most of my cases, just stripping out those characters is much simpler:

```
s = mystring.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: "Perfectly" is not usually what it performs.  It throws away stuff which you should figure out how to deal with properly.

Comment: just stripping out "those" (non-english) characters is not the solution since python must support all languages dont you think?

Comment: Downvoted. This is not the correct solution at all. Learn how to work with Unicode: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Agreed. Downvoted because if you actually took time to watch Ned Batchelder's unicode pain video you'd know why.

Comment: Look, the most judicious way to present this particular answer is in this way: recognizing that ascii confers a certain privilege on certain languages and users - this is the _escape hatch_ that may be exploited for those users who may be hacking a cursory, first pass, script together potentially for preliminary work before full unicode support is implemented.

Comment: If I'm writing a script that just needs to print english text to stdout in an internal company application, I just want the problem to go away. Whatever works.

Comment: This is plain wrong. I want my package/courier to be delivered and just because authorities cant figure out how to put them in shipping/ how to categorize them (say encoding) they must not ignore my package/courier. I want them delivered right

Answer (score 29):

For me, what worked was:

```
BeautifulSoup(html_text,from_encoding="utf-8")
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a rehashing of some other so-called "cop out" answers.  There are situations in which simply throwing away the troublesome characters/strings is a good solution, despite the protests voiced here.

```
def safeStr(obj):
    try: return str(obj)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return obj.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    except: return ""
```

Testing it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    print safeStr( 1 ) 
    print safeStr( "test" ) 
    print u'98\xb0'
    print safeStr( u'98\xb0' )
```

Results:

```
1
test
98°
98
```

**UPDATE:** My original answer was written for Python 2. For **Python 3**:

```
def safeStr(obj):
    try: return str(obj).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    except: return ""
```

Note: if you'd prefer to leave a `?` indicator where the "unsafe" unicode characters are, specify `replace` instead of `ignore` in the call to encode for the error handler.

Suggestion: you might want to name this function `toAscii` instead?  That's a matter of preference...

Finally, here's a more robust PY2/3 version using `six`, where I opted to use `replace`, and peppered in some character swaps to replace fancy unicode quotes and apostrophes which curl left or right with the simple vertical ones that are part of the ascii set.  You might expand on such swaps yourself:

```
from six import PY2, iteritems 

CHAR_SWAP = { u'\u201c': u'"'
            , u'\u201D': u'"' 
            , u'\u2018': u"'" 
            , u'\u2019': u"'" 
}

def toAscii( text ) :    
    try:
        for k,v in iteritems( CHAR_SWAP ): 
            text = text.replace(k,v)
    except: pass     
    try: return str( text ) if PY2 else bytes( text, 'replace' ).decode('ascii')
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return text.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('ascii')
    except: return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':     
    print( toAscii( u'testin\u2019' ) )
```

Answer (score 18):

Add line below at the beginning of your script ( or as second line):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

That's definition of python source code encoding. More info in [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Comment: This does not solve the problem when processed text loaded from external file contains utf-8 encodings. This helps only for literals written in the given python script itself and is just a clue for python interpreter, but has no impact on text processing.

Answer (score 12):

I always put the code below in the first two lines of the python files:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Comment: Thank you soo much ! I didn't understand why it was working on other scripts and not on this one. The answer is the from _future_ missing ;)

Answer (score 12):

It works for me:

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 10):

*Alas this works in Python 3 at least...*

**Python 3**

Sometimes the error is in the enviroment variables and enconding so

```
import os
import locale
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"
myLocale=locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL, locale="en_GB.UTF-8")
... 
print(myText.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))
```

where errors are ignored in encoding.

Answer (score 10):

In case its an issue with a print statement, a lot fo times its just an issue with the terminal printing. This helped me :
`export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`

Answer (score 8):

Simple helper functions found [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/466341-guaranteed-conversion-to-unicode-or-byte-string/).

```
def safe_unicode(obj, *args):
    """ return the unicode representation of obj """
    try:
        return unicode(obj, *args)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        # obj is byte string
        ascii_text = str(obj).encode('string_escape')
        return unicode(ascii_text)

def safe_str(obj):
    """ return the byte string representation of obj """
    try:
        return str(obj)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        # obj is unicode
        return unicode(obj).encode('unicode_escape')
```

Comment: To get the escaped bytestring (to convert arbitrary Unicode string to bytes using ascii encoding), you could use `backslashreplace` error handler: `u'\xa0'.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')`. Though you should avoid such representation and configure your environment to accept non-ascii characters instead -- it is 2016!

Answer (score 8):

Just add to a variable encode('utf-8')

```
agent_contact.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 8):

Please open terminal and fire the below command:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 7):

Late answer, but this error is related to your terminal's encoding not supporting certain characters.
I fixed it on `python3` using:

```
import sys
import io

sys.stdout = io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', encoding='utf8')
print("é, à, ...")
```

Answer (score 6):

I just used the following:

```
import unicodedata
message = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", message)
```

Check what documentation says about it:

> unicodedata.normalize(form, unistr) Return the normal form form for
>   the Unicode string unistr. Valid values for form are ‘NFC’, ‘NFKC’,
>   ‘NFD’, and ‘NFKD’.
>
> The Unicode standard defines various normalization forms of a Unicode
>   string, based on the definition of canonical equivalence and
>   compatibility equivalence. In Unicode, several characters can be
>   expressed in various way. For example, the character U+00C7 (LATIN
>   CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA) can also be expressed as the sequence
>   U+0043 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C) U+0327 (COMBINING CEDILLA).
>
> For each character, there are two normal forms: normal form C and
>   normal form D. Normal form D (NFD) is also known as canonical
>   decomposition, and translates each character into its decomposed form.
>   Normal form C (NFC) first applies a canonical decomposition, then
>   composes pre-combined characters again.
>
> In addition to these two forms, there are two additional normal forms
>   based on compatibility equivalence. In Unicode, certain characters are
>   supported which normally would be unified with other characters. For
>   example, U+2160 (ROMAN NUMERAL ONE) is really the same thing as U+0049
>   (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I). However, it is supported in Unicode for
>   compatibility with existing character sets (e.g. gb2312).
>
> The normal form KD (NFKD) will apply the compatibility decomposition,
>   i.e. replace all compatibility characters with their equivalents. The
>   normal form KC (NFKC) first applies the compatibility decomposition,
>   followed by the canonical composition.
>
> Even if two unicode strings are normalized and look the same to a
>   human reader, if one has combining characters and the other doesn’t,
>   they may not compare equal.

Solves it for me. Simple and easy.

Answer (score 5):

Below solution worked for me, Just added

> u "String"

(representing the string as unicode) before my string.

```
result_html = result.to_html(col_space=1, index=False, justify={'right'})

text = u"""
<html>
<body>
<p>
Hello all, <br>
<br>
Here's weekly summary report.  Let me know if you have any questions. <br>
<br>
Data Summary <br>
<br>
<br>
{0}
</p>
<p>Thanks,</p>
<p>Data Team</p>
</body></html>
""".format(result_html)
```

Answer (score 5):

The recommended solution did not work for me, and I could live with dumping all non ascii characters, so

```
s = s.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
```

which left me with something stripped that doesn't throw errors.

Answer (score 5):

In general case of writing this *unsupported encoding* **string** (let's say `data_that_causes_this_error`) to some file (for e.g. `results.txt`), this works

```
f = open("results.txt", "w")
  f.write(data_that_causes_this_error.encode('utf-8'))
  f.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem, and Google led me here, so just to add to the general solutions here, this is what worked for me:

```
# 'value' contains the problematic data
unic = u''
unic += value
value = unic
```

I had this idea after reading [Ned's presentation](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

I don't claim to fully understand why this works, though. So if anyone can edit this answer or put in a comment to explain, I'll appreciate it.

Comment: What is the `type` of value? before and after this? I think why that works is that by doing a `unic += value` which is the same as `unic = unic + value` you are adding a string and a unicode, where python then assumes unicode for the resultant `unic` i.e. the more precise type (think about when you do this `a = float(1) + int(1)`, `a` becomes a float) and then `value = unic` points `value` to the new `unic` object which happens to be unicode.

Answer (score 4):

We struck this error when running `manage.py migrate` in Django with localized fixtures.

Our source contained the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` declaration, MySQL was correctly configured for utf8 and Ubuntu had the appropriate language pack and values in `/etc/default/locale`.

The issue was simply that the Django container (we use docker) was missing the `LANG` env var.

Setting `LANG` to `en_US.UTF-8` and restarting the container before re-running migrations fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Update for python 3.0 and later. Try the following in the python editor:

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US.en
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

This sets the system`s default locale encoding to the UTF-8 format.

More can be read [here at PEP 538 -- Coercing the legacy C locale to a UTF-8 based locale](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0538/).

Answer (score 3):

Many answers here (@agf and @Andbdrew for example) have already addressed the most immediate aspects of the OP question.

However, I think there is one subtle but important aspect that has been largely ignored and that matters dearly for everyone who like me ended up here while trying to make sense of encodings in Python: **Python 2 vs Python 3 management of character representation  is wildly different**. I feel like a big chunk of confusion out there has to do with people reading about encodings in Python without being version aware.

I suggest anyone interested in understanding the root cause of OP problem to begin by reading [Spolsky's](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) introduction to character representations and Unicode and then move to [Batchelder](https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/pragmatic-unicode-or-how-do-i-stop-the-pain.html) on Unicode in Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: yes, my error was on python 2.7, 'a'.format(u'ñ'), and the correct solution is not to use .encode('utf-8') but use always unicode strings, (the default in python 3):  u'a'.format(u'ñ'),

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid conversion of variable to str(variable). Sometimes, It may cause the issue.

Simple tip to avoid :

```
try: 
    data=str(data)
except:
    data = data #Don't convert to String
```

The above example will solve Encode error also.

Comment: this doens't work as you'll just run into the error in the except

Answer (score 1):

If you have something like `packet_data = "This is data"` then do this on the next line, right after initializing `packet_data`:

```
unic = u''
packet_data = unic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the character encoding to `UTF-8` before running your script:

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

This should generally resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue trying to output Unicode characters to `stdout`, but with `sys.stdout.write`, rather than print (so that I could support output to a different file as well).

[From BeautifulSoup's own documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Why%20can't%20Beautiful%20Soup%20print%20out%20the%20non-ASCII%20characters%20I%20gave%20it?), I solved this with the codecs library:

```
import sys
import codecs

def main(fIn, fOut):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fIn)
    # Do processing, with data including non-ASCII characters
    fOut.write(unicode(soup))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with (sys.stdin) as fIn: # Don't think we need codecs.getreader here
        with codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout) as fOut:
            main(fIn, fOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem often happens  when a django project deploys using Apache. Because Apache sets environment variable LANG=C in /etc/sysconfig/httpd. Just open the file and comment (or change to your flavior) this setting. Or use the lang option of the WSGIDaemonProcess command, in this case you will be able to set different LANG environment variable  to different virtualhosts.

Answer (score 0):

**This will work:**

```
 >>>print(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", "bats\xc3\xa0")).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

**Output:**

```
>>>bats
```

Answer (score -1):

You can you use unicodedata for avoid UnicodeEncodeError. here is an example:

```
import unicodedata

agent_telno = agent.find('div', 'agent_contact_number')
agent_telno = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", agent_telno) #it will remove all unwanted character like '\xa0'
agent_telno = '' if agent_telno is None else agent_telno.contents[0]
p.agent_info = str(agent_contact + ' ' + agent_telno).strip()
```