# Cannot get django template tag to return unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-templates

I'm writing an app that will track a series of matches between 2 players. I am using Django's `User` model and extending it with my own `UserProfile`.

I store usernames in `User` as their steamID (ex: `76561197965801299`) and then look up their steam username on login, and update `UserProfile`.

Instead of looking at `76561197965801299`, I want to look at a username, and on one page, I want to decorate this username with more goodies, so I wrote a template tag.

**Problem**:

I cannot seem to print unicode data from my template tag.

**Actual Error**:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u260e' in position 16: ordinal
>   not in range(128)

Normally Django doesn't bother me with unicode issues (for example: I can see this unicode object in the admin pages no problem) but I've never tried applying a template tag, so there is obviously something I'm doing wrong here.

**template/ladder/match_game_listing.html**

```
{{ match.challengee|steam_name }}
```

The `match.challengee` in this case is `76561197971597000`.

**ladder/templatetags/ladder_filters.py**

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
from cafe.models import UserProfile

register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def steam_name(name):
    try:
        user_obj = User.objects.get(username=name)
        user_prof = UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=user_obj.id)

        url = user_prof.url
        handle = unicode(user_prof.handle)
        avatar = user_prof.avatar

        steam_string = "<a href='{0}' alt='{1}\'s profile'><img src='{2}' alt='{1}\'s avatar' >{1}</a>".format(url, handle, avatar)

        return mark_safe(steam_string)

    # Non-steam entities can exist, ignore
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return name
```

When I go to view this in the browser, I get the aforementioned error:

> UnicodeEncodeError at /ladder/dota2/ 'ascii' codec can't encode
>   character u'\u260e' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)

With a helpful hint of:

> Unicode error hint
>
> The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: oose ☎

I've tried browsing the Django docs numerous times, and I have tried playing with `force_text()` to no avail, but as I'm a little unclear on why this isn't working, I might just be missing the relevant section. This template tag works in cases where the name does not have unicode.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/q/3828723/165603 help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
steam_string = "<a href='{0}' alt='{1}\'s profile'><img src='{2}' alt='{1}\'s avatar' >{1}</a>".format(url, handle, avatar)
```

The `.format()` method won't promote a format string from bytes to unicode just because there are unicode strings in the formatting parameters. The output of `str.format` is always `str` and the output of `unicode.format` is always `unicode`. In this way it differs from the old `%` operator, where `str % unicode -> unicode`.

Since you want Unicode output, your format string needs to be Unicode (`u""` string) too. Also,

```
return mark_safe(steam_string)
```

Why are you marking this safe? It isn't. Without HTML-escaping, any HTML-special characters in the formatted parameters can cause an HTML-injection vulnerability leading to XSS attacks. Also your apostrophes are mis-escaped:

```
"alt='{1}\'s profile'"
```

`\'` is a Python string literal escape; you will be returning the string:

```
alt='someone's profile'
```

which means you'll never see the `'s profile` suffix as it isn't part of the attribute value.

Suggest:

```
from django.utils.html import escape
...
return mark_safe(
    u'<a href="{0}" alt="{1}\'s profile">'
        u'<img src="{2}" alt="{1}\'s avatar">{1}'
    u'</a>'
).format(escape(url), escape(handle), escape(avatar))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is also what I was hoping for - I had a feeling that I was doing something quite wrong with this. This has been immensely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I might be thinking this very simply and in a wrong way but, maybe if you just tell django its a unicode by putting the letter 'u' before the string.

something like:

```
unicodeString = "ís"
string = u"this -> %s my unicode string" % unicodeString
```

I'm sorry if i didn't understand your question at all. (i can't comment so i posted an answer)

Got that from reading this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/

Comment: Oh man do *I* feel silly. This is exactly the problem. Overthinking it to the max, thank you so much.

Comment: I use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` on Python 2 and use Unicode everywhere I go.

Comment: This code is wrong - your unicodeString is a bytestring (encoded using source code encoding), and it will be decoded with sys.getdefaultencoding() during the interpolation. If these encodings doesn't match, you'll get either incorrect result or an exception.

Comment: But since there's a "u" in the start of the sentence, wouldn't it convert to a unicode when attributing the value to string ?