# How to write a function to check if a list of modules are present or not, else install modules in Python

Tags: python, function, if-statement, python-module

I want to write a 'If Else' function in Python to check if a list of modules are present or not,  else install modules in Python (3.6).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good idea! What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a python module has been imported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483246/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-has-been-imported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import os
def checkModules(module_list):
    missing = []
    for m in module_list:
        try:
            exec("import %s" % m)
        except ImportError:
            missing.append(m)
    if len(missing) > 0:
        os.system("python -m pip install %s" % ' '.join(missing))
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules

> This is a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have
>   already been loaded.