# importlib.reload module from string?

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib

I want to use `importlib` to reload a module whose name is dynamically generated.

Example:

```
import sys

def some_func():
    return "sys"

want_reload = some_func()
```

Now how do I reload the module `sys` using the variable `want_reload`? I can't supply it directly to `importlib.reload()` because it says it expects a module, not str.

It would be better if an invalid string, or a module that's not loaded, is supplied, e.g. `"........"`, that it raises an exception.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`importlib.import_module()` won't reload, but returns a ref to the module even if already loaded:

```
import sys
import importlib

def some_func():
    return "sys"

want_reload = some_func()
want_reload_module = importlib.import_module(want_reload)
importlib.reload(want_reload_module)
```

Comment: I want to avoid that, if a module is not loaded, don't load it. Right now it seems `importlib.import_module` will import the module if it's not loaded already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that gave me a useful hint!

Comment: np. Hmm so you want to reload a module but only if it is loaded. That is not clear from your question. But anyway, loaded modules are listed in [sys,modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483246/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-has-been-imported#30483269)

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought. See my own answer below that takes it exactly.

Answer (score 5):

Hinted by @spinkus's answer, I came up with this solution:

Since I don't want to load a module if it's not loaded already, I can fetch the ref from `sys.modules`

```
want_reload = some_func()
try:
    want_reload_module = sys.modules[want_reload]
    importlib.reload(want_reload_module)
except KeyError:
    raise ImportError("Module {} not loaded. Can't reload".format(want_reload))
```

Comment: would be better to check if want_reload in sys.modules, instead of just using a try-except to catch the inevitable errors

Comment: When attempting to reload a local module (relative import) I get "ModuleNotFoundError: spec not found for the module 'block'" is there any way to create this spec or avoid this error?