# Check if method is imported, from X import Y

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, sys, python-3.7

In Python 3.7 I would like to import few methos and use them later in the same script. Before that I would like to check if they are correctly imported.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30483269/1008588) answer I can check if a module is fully imported into the script but how if I imported only one method with the `form from X import Y`?

**What I have done**

I have done the following snippet:

```
from shapely.geometry import asShape
from shapely.geometry import Point
import sys

if 'shapely.geometry.asshape' in sys.modules:
  print('Shapely Geometry asshape ok')
else:
  print('Shapely Geometry asshape NOT loaded')
  
if 'shapely.geometry.point' in sys.modules:
  print('Shapely Geometry point ok')
else:
  print('Shapely Geometry point NOT loaded')
```

which gives me the following results:

> Shapely Geometry asshape NOT loaded
>
> Shapely Geometry point ok

**Duplicate question**

I don't this this is a duplicate question as all other questions here on SO are about check if a module is imported (with the form `import Z`) and not only some methods.

Comment: If you import a name from a module in Python, the module is interpreted, stored in `sys.modules` and the name is referenced from that module into your import namespace. If you import an other name from the same module it is reuse from `sys.modules` and a new reference is created only.

Comment: You don't have to check if a name is "correctly imported" - an import either succeed or raises an ImportError.  Also, 'Point' is a class (not a module) defined in `shapely.geometry.point` (and imported by shapely.geometry cf https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/geometry/__init__.py, which is why you find 'shapely.geometry.point' in sys.modules), and ` asShape` is a function defined in  `shapely.geometry.geo` - there's no `shapely.geometry.asshape` _module_ so of course you won't find it in sys.modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you import just one function from a module, or import the whole module itself, whole module is always imported into `sys.modules`. So, in your case, you'll have to check for imported module instead of the function:

```
'shapely.geometry' in sys.modules
```

Check out this qustion ['import module' vs. 'from module import function'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function).

Answer (score 2):

The built-in function dir() will give you a list which includes all imports. Your locally imported functions will appear there as well. You can check using:

```
'myFunction' in dir ()
```