# Check Upstream Python Package/Module Imports

Tags: python

In Python, is there a way to determine which module/package imported a downstream package? For example, imagine if we have `package_A`, `package_B`, and `package_C`. In my scenario, both `package_A` and `package_B` depend on `package_C`. So, if I import `package_A`, `package_C` automatically gets imported. Similarly, if I import `package_B`, `package_C` automatically gets imported.

Assuming that I can change/modify `package_C`, is there a way to determine whether `package_C` was imported by `package_A` or `package_B` or neither? In other words, I want to add code to `package_C` that will detect whether the parent importer included `package_A`, `package_B`, or neither. Note that `package_A` may not be directly importing `package_C` (i.e., `package_A` might import `package_Q`, which imports `package_C`).

I've tried looking at `traceback` but I'm not able to make any progress.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a module has been imported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483246/how-can-i-check-if-a-module-has-been-imported)

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherPeisert. I think this is closer but it doesn't tell me that `package_A` imports `package_Q`, which then imports `package_C`. It's possible that somebody imports `package_A.other_module`, which does not import `package_C` downstream and maybe `package_C` is imported in, say, `__main__`. So, I'm looking for some sort of lineage or "importing stack" if such a thing exists