# Is there a pythonic unit testing way to assert that a function has been imported successfully?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-import, assert

Let's say we have the following simple file structure:

```sh
- some_file.py
- tests.py
```

The file `some_file.py` should contain the function `foo`, but how do I confirm that using the `unittest` framework?

I could see doing something like this within `tests.py`:

```py
try:
   from some_file import foo
except ImportError as error:
   print('Error! Could not find foo.)
```

... but I am curious if there is a way to do this with assertions instead of a try-except block.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483246/how-can-i-check-if-a-module-has-been-imported) is pretty comprehensive about testing the imports on modules themselves, but I don't actually see anything about functions within the file, unless I'm overlooking something.

Comment: @Asa try-except is pythonic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use several approaches:

- Just import the function without try-except. If it doesn't raise an exception it counts as a passed test. However, if it does, it counts as an *error* and not as a *failure*.
- Change the import from `from some_file import foo` to `import some_file` and add an assertion `assertTrue(hasattr(some_file, 'foo'))`. This has the benefit that you are now explicitly testing that something called `foo` exists in `some_file` and not that you can import `some_file`.

Comment: Fantastic, the second bullet point was exactly what I was looking for in my use case. Thank you!