# Scrapy linkextractors fail

Tags: python, html-parsing, scrapy

I am failing alot with Srapys link extractors. E.g:

```
scrapy shell "http://www.dachser.com/de/de/"
# within shell
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
SgmlLinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
# yields: SGMLParseError: expected name token at '<!/IoRangeRedDotMode'
```

Now, i only require a list of all links which is why i switched from `SgmlLinkExtractor` to the basic `HtmlParserLinkExtractor`. This works for the url above, but lets take another url and even this fails:

```
scrapy shell "http://www.yourfirm.de"
# within shell
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.htmlparser import HtmlParserLinkExtractor
HtmlParserLinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
# yields: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Whats going on here? I plan on extracting the links for various websites so a more foolproof link extraction would be very much welcomed.

Update: Okay, i figured out that the ascii error can be resolved on Windows by setting `utf-8` as the systemdefault encoding, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-we-need-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script). Now others fail though.. Like `scrapy shell "http://grunwald-wangen.de"`  causing `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 17: invalid start byte`.

Comment: The second example works fine for me ! I have Scrapy 0.22.2.

Comment: I updated to `0.22.2` but it is still the same. I've read that sometimes the stdout can yield encoding errors depending on the terminal. But i do not think this is the case here, for my script i redirected the output to a log `LOG_FILE = "spider.log"` but still the error remains. Python 2.7.7, Scrapy 0.22.2, Windows 7 64-Bit.

Comment: Have you tried a different website?

Comment: `HtmlParserLinkExtractor` works with `http://www.google.de`, `http://www.dachser.com/de/de/` for example but fails at `http://www.yourfirm.de` or `http://www.crossvertise.com/werbung/deutschland/werbung-berlin/` for example.

Comment: That's a problem inside the used webpages. Both examples are working fine with different webpages using `Scrapy 0.22.2`. Have a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/iA1VzcJYpJE for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `HtmlParserLinkExtractor` passes the `response.body` to the `HTMLParser`.

Altering the source code so that it recevies `response.body_as_unicode()` fixes the issue. The [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/htmlparser.html?highlight=parser#HTMLParser.HTMLParser.feed) states that `unicode` is advised. I made a [pull request](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/756) on github.

As Berendt stated in the comments, the `SgmlLinkExtractor` seems to choke on some malformed HTMLs.