# Django: cannot upload data with spanish characters using a command

Tags: python, pandas

I've configured my Django Apps to use commands to upload data from CSV Files.

**Note**: destionation DataBase is `PostgreSQL`, but for testing in local machine I just use `SQLite`.

I read the CSV file with this line:

```
tmp_data_products=pd.read_csv('static/data/products.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8").fillna(" ")
```

Data:

If I only use the first line no problem occurs:

```
| category | product                           | slug                              | description                                                   | image                                                                               | available 
|----------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|---------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------
| Muestras | Sobre con stickers de muestra     | sobre-con-stickers-de-muestra     | Sobre con 10 stickers de muestra                              | https://stickers-files.s3.amazonaws.com/product/Artboard_1_PNG.png | True 
| Muestras | Stickers transparentes de muestra | stickers-transparentes-de-muestra | Sobre con 10 stickers de muestra con el diseño que tú envíes. | https://stickers-files.s3.amazonaws.com/product/Artboard_1_PNG.png | True
```

> It works perfect when I don't have any spanish characters in my CSV
>   file. But when there are `ñ` or accents `tú` I get an error about
>   encoding.

**Error:**

```
(stickers-gallito-app) D:\web_proyects\stickers-gallito-app>python manage.py products
DEBUG ON
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1134, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1240, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1256, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1494, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 44: invalid continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 19, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 224, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Users\OGONZALES\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\web_proyects\stickers-gallito-app\shop\management\commands\products.py", line 8, in <module>
    tmp_data_products=pd.read_csv('static/data/products.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8").fillna(" ")
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1036, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "D:\virtual_envs\stickers-gallito-app\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1848, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 968, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1094, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1141, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1240, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1256, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1494, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 44: invalid continuation byte
```

I've search and found this other question:

[Pandas df.to_csv("file.csv" encode="utf-8") still gives trash characters for minus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788037/pandas-df-to-csvfile-csv-encode-utf-8-still-gives-trash-characters-for-min/43684587#43684587)

Tried the answer, without success. Using `encoding='utf-8-sig'` made no difference.

**Full Command to upload data:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from shop.models import Product, Category
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand



tmp_data_products=pd.read_csv('static/data/products.csv',sep=',', encoding="utf-8").fillna(" ")




class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        products = [
            Product(
                category=Category.objects.get(name=row['category']),
                name=row['product'],
                slug=row['slug'],
                description=row['description'],
                available=row['available']
        )
            for _, row in tmp_data_products.iterrows()
        ]

        Product.objects.bulk_create(products)
```

**models.py**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True, null=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    def get_url(self):
            return reverse('shop:ProdDetail', args=[self.category.slug, self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

**settings.py**:

```
import os

# SITE_ROOT = root()


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '^_67&#r+(c+%pu&n+a%&dmxql^i^_$0f69)mnhf@)zq-rbxe9z'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'stickers-gallito-app.herokuapp.com',
                 'stickersgallito.pe', 'www.stickersgallito.pe']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'shop',
    'search_app',
    'cart',
    'stripe',
    'order',
    'crispy_forms',
    'embed_video',
    'storages',
    'marketing',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'stickers_gallito.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'shop', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'search_app', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'cart', 'templates/'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'order', 'templates/'), ]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'shop.context_processor.menu_links',
                'shop.context_processor.has_shop',
                # 'cart.context_processor.current_time',
                'cart.context_processor.cart_items_counter'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stickers_gallito.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases
# Redirecciona www y http  a https
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

if DEBUG:
    print("DEBUG ON")
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        }
    }

else:

    ### HEROKU POSTGRESS ACCESS

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
            'NAME': 'xxxxxx',
            'USER': 'xxxxxx',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxxxxx1',
            'HOST': 'xxxxxxamazonaws.com',
            'PORT': 'xxxxx',
        }
    }


####

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'

####


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

### CULQUI ###


CULQI_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = os.environ['CULQI_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']

CULQI_SECRET_KEY = os.environ['CULQI_SECRET_KEY']

# DO NOT DO THIS!
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = os.environ['MAILCHIMP_API_KEY']
MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER = os.environ['MAILCHIMP_DATA_CENTER']
MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID = os.environ['MAILCHIMP_EMAIL_LIST_ID']

### AMAZON ###


AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=94608000',
}

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ['AWS_S3_REGION_NAME']
# Tell django-storages the domain to use to refer to static files.
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

### MAILGUN - EMAIL MESSAGE SETTINGS ###

EMAIL_HOST = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST']
EMAIL_PORT = os.environ['EMAIL_PORT']
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.environ['EMAIL_USE_TLS']
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_USER']
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ['EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD']
```

Comment: Python tells you that encoding is not utf-8, by saying unknown character `0xf1`

Comment: @deathangel908  ty. So what encoding should I use for those spanish characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions for your problem.

First of all check the section of encoding here in the official Django docs.
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/unicode/)
Try using django.utils.encoding module

> Conversion functions¶
>
> The django.utils.encoding module contains a few functions that are
>   handy for converting back and forth between strings and bytestrings.

Also use this tip:

> import sys sys.getfilesystemencoding()
>
> export LANG="es_ES.iso-8859-1" (if I am catching Spanish encoding correct)
>   (double check what version of Spanish you're going to use)

Another one option is to pass Spanish encoding through view, when generating project:

```
def some_view(request):
    request.encoding = 'iso-8859-1'
    ...
```

Comment: No view is generating this data, it's created via a command (please, see last part of question), so where should I put  `request.encoding`?

Comment: @deathangel908 yes, this worked. I'll need to learn more about encoding types.

Comment: @PirrenCode `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` shows 'utf-8'