# pandas to_csv converts the ' ' ', ' " ' and ' ' to 'â€™s', 'â€', 'Â'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, utf-8

```
def store_data(company, url, title, date, text):
    data = {'company_id': [], 'title':[],'date':[], 'link':[], 'main_headline':[] ,'main_headline_text':[]}
    
    data['company_id'].append('example')
    data['title'].append(title)
    data['date'].append(date)
    data['link'].append(url)
    data['main_headline'].append(title)
    data['main_headline_text'].append(text)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv(company+'10k'+'.csv', index=False, line_terminator='\n')
    return df
```

'text' is a string. when the data frame gets stored to csv, the following changes occur.

**original text :** The move is in alignment with abc Group’s vision of “building a world-leading clean energy and chemical company” and its development pattern of “One Foundation, Two Wings and Three Growth Points”, creating synergy of financial investment with industry, and contributing to another big step of abc in new energy and new materials.

**text in csv :** The move is in alignment with **abc Groupâ€™s** vision of **â€œbuilding** a world-leading clean energy and chemical **companyâ€** and its development pattern of **â€œOne** Foundation, Two Wings and Three Growth **Pointsâ€**, creating synergy of financial investment with industry, and contributing to another big step of abc in new energy and new materials.

why is this happening? how can I avoid it so that the original text, even if it's not in english, comes as it is in the csv?

Comment: Looks like you're reading a UTF8 file using a single-byte codepage, eg Latin1. There's nothing wrong with the file. How are. you reading this file? The smart quotes in the original text aren't part of the ASCII range so they're encoded using 2 or more bytes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas df.to\_csv("file.csv" encode="utf-8") still gives trash characters for minus sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788037/pandas-df-to-csvfile-csv-encode-utf-8-still-gives-trash-characters-for-min)

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos text is a string, that I scraped using beautifulSoup get_text(). How can I get the original text in the csv ?

Comment: That *is* the original text. Again, how are you reading it? There's nothing wrong with the file. The problem is the editor

Comment: I'm opening the csv using excel and seeing.

Comment: Read the duplicate then. BTW you aren't just opening the file in Excel (from the Data menu). You're double-clicking on it. Unless the file has a BOM, Excel can't guess the encoding so it *imports* the text using the encoding of the user's locale

Comment: yes, I am. When I open the csv in a text editor, it looks fine. When I open it in excel, by double clicking on it, it shows the encoded version. What do you mean 'read the duplicate' ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos oh! alright. now I understood. so is there a way to specify a bom to the file?

Comment: Read the duplicate