# Unicode Error when using NLTK to find trigrams for entire corpus and print to csv

Tags: python, unicode, nltk, trigram

I'm trying to go through a whole folder of text files, collect a cumulative frequency of trigrams across all of those files, and print them to a csv file. It does the whole corpus thing but then when it starts to do the work for the trigrams I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entireCRngrams.py", line 23, in <module>
    raw = speeches.raw().encode('ascii', 'ignore').lower()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.py", line 74, in raw
    return concat([self.open(f).read() for f in fileids])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/api.py", line 198, in open
    stream = self._root.join(file).open(encoding)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/data.py", line 309, in join
    return FileSystemPathPointer(_path)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 85: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Thank you so much in advance. Here's the script:

```
import nltk
import re
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader
import os
import math 
from decimal import *
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer, WhitespaceTokenizer, word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
import csv
import string
from nltk.tokenize.punkt import PunktWordTokenizer

#this imports the text files in the folder into corpus called speeches
corpus_root = '/Users/jolijttamanaha/Documents/Senior/Thesis/Python/DailyNews'
speeches = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, '.*\.txt')

print "Finished importing corpus"

for infile in sorted(speeches.fileids()):
    print infile # The fileids of each file.

raw = speeches.raw().lower()
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(raw.encode('utf-8').translate(None, string.punctuation))
tgs = nltk.trigrams(tokens)
fdist = nltk.FreqDist(tgs)
for k,v in fdist.items():
    print k,v


minscore = 1
numwords = len(raw)    
print "Words in corpus:" 
print numwords
c = csv.writer(open("ngrams.csv", "a"))
for k,v in fdist.items():
    if v > minscore:
        rf = Decimal(v)/Decimal(numwords)
        firstword, secondword, thirdword = k #splits up the list hidden in k 
        trigram = firstword + " " + secondword + " " + thirdword #turns the list in k into one string
        time = year+ month + set
        results = time,trigram,v,rf 
        c.writerow(results)

print "All done."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

see [Why should we NOT use sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") in a py script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-we-need-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script)

It's a pesky issue in py2.7 and nltk

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to write Unicode to a text file, try `codecs.open("ngrams.csv")` instead of `open("ngrams.csv", "a")` so as to open the .csv file as a unicode file.

Looking at your traceback the line that is being complained about is:

```
raw = speeches.raw().lower()
```

Try changing this to:

```
raw = speeches.raw().encode('utf-8', 'ignore').lower()
```