# Python2.7 prints wrong characters from unicode with hexadecimal chars

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, hex, unicode-string

```
sys.getdefaultencoding()
-> utf8
test = u'tempête'
test
-> u'temp\xc3\xaate'
print(test)
-> tempÃªte # WTF ?

sys.setdefaultencoding('ascii')
sys.getdefaultencoding()
-> ascii
test = u'tempête'
test
-> u'temp\xc3\xaate'
print(test)
-> tempÃªte #...
```

I observe these results when I do a set_trace() from pdb.

In a python2.7 shell I have correct result :

```
sys.getdefaultencoding()
-> ascii
test = u'tempête'
test
-> u'temp\xc3\xaate'
print(test)
-> tempÃªte # WTF ?
```

I'm struggling with this from hours...

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem with python 2.7

Comment: In python2.7 shell, I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CodecInfo'`

Comment: Please show us the shell output directly.

Comment: Python 2.x should never have a default encoding of UTF-8. You would've had to `reload(sys)` to make this work, which should tell you that it's not supposed to be played with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has created a more accurate representation of the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648216/python-scrapy-bad-utf8-characters-writed-in-file-from-scraped-html-page-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your `locale` encoding matches your terminal emulation. Type `locale` to check.

`sys.setdefaultencoding()` has nothing to do with printing - Python uses your locale to set the stdout encoding used when printing. See `sys.stdout.encoding`.

I can partially replicate your problem like this:

1. Set terminal emulation to: `UTF-8`
2. Set locale to en_GB.ISO8859-1. I.e. Not UTF-8

   ```
   export LANG=en_GB.ISO8859-1
   ```
3. Run your code:

   ```
   >>> test = u'tempête'
   >>> test
   u'temp\xc3\xaate'
   ```

The fact that `ê` becomes Ã (U+00C3) and ª(U+00AA) is the crux of the problem, showing that Python thought the encoding of should be an 8bit character set.

I can't replicate your final print but I suspect fiddling with `setdefaultencoding()` and cooked everything - See my answer about why it's a bad idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34378962/1554386

Comment: Thank your for your answer and the one you linked to, very interseting ! But I still have a problem, not sure if it's related finally...I'm scraping a web page with charset `iso-8859-1`, scrapy returns an utf-8 unicode response. The text to scrap is 'tempête', I've put a `pdb.set_trace()` statement to check the response and it's correct : `u'temp\xc3\xaate'`, but when I tried to `print` it, the same problem as above occurs : `print(response) -> tempÃªte`. I'm trying to put this response in json file, and that's also what is printed in the json file instead of 'tempête'. Any clue on this ?

Comment: Ok, this is a typical [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Too many assumptions have been made when the problem is probably quite simple in the original code. Please update the question with the actual scraping code instead.

Comment: Maybe should I create a whole new questions to keep the coms & answer in sync with the old subject ?

Comment: Good idea. Create a new question and paste a link here so I can help you again.

Comment: Here the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648216/python-scrapy-bad-utf8-characters-writed-in-file-from-scraped-html-page-with