# Python, scrapy : bad utf8 characters writed in file from scraped html page with charset iso-8859-1

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding, scrapy

I want to scrap a webpage with charset `iso-8859-1` with Scrapy, in python 2.7. The text i'm interesting in on the webpage is : `tempête`

Scrapy returns response as an UTF8 unicode with characters correctly encoded :

```
>>> response
u'temp\xc3\xaate'
```

Now, I want to write the word `tempête` in a file, so I'm doing the following :

```
>>> import codecs
>>> file = codecs.open('test', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
>>> file.write(response) #response is the above var
```

When I open the file, the resulting text is `tempÃªte`. It seems that python does not detect proper encoding and can't read the two bytes encoded char and thinks it's two one-coded char.

How can I handle this simple use case ?

Comment: Your response is not "**UTF8** Unicode", it's just Unicode. Scrapy is incorrectly parsing UTF-8 content as iso-8859-1. Can you provide a little more of the Scrapy code please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, `response` is a (decoded) Unicode string with `\xc3\xa` inside, then something is wrong at scrapy encoding detection level.

`\xc3\xa` is character `ê` encoded as UTF-8, so you should only see those character for (encoded) non-Unicode/`str` strings (in Python 2 that is)

Python 2.7 shell session:

```
>>> # what your input should look like
>>> tempete = u'tempête'
>>> tempete
u'temp\xeate'

>>> # UTF-8 encoded
>>> tempete.encode('utf-8')
'temp\xc3\xaate'
>>>
>>> # latin1 encoded
>>> tempete.encode('iso-8859-1')
'temp\xeate'
>>> 

>>> # back to your sample
>>> s = u'temp\xc3\xaate'
>>> print s
tempÃªte
>>>
>>> # if you use a non-Unicode string with those characters...
>>> s_raw = 'temp\xc3\xaate'
>>> s_raw.decode('utf-8')
u'temp\xeate'
>>> 
>>> # ... decoding from UTF-8 works
>>> print s_raw.decode('utf-8')
tempête
>>>
```

Something is wrong with Scrapy interpreting page as `iso-8859-1` encoded.

You can force the encoding by re-building a response from `response.body`:

```
>>> import scrapy.http
>>> hr1 = scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(url='http://www.example', body='<html><body>temp\xc3\xaate</body></html>', encoding='latin1')
>>> hr1.body_as_unicode()
u'<html><body>temp\xc3\xaate</body></html>'
>>> hr2 = scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(url='http://www.example', body='<html><body>temp\xc3\xaate</body></html>', encoding='utf-8')
>>> hr2.body_as_unicode()
u'<html><body>temp\xeate</body></html>'
>>>
```

Build a new reponse

```
newresponse = response.replace(encoding='utf-8')
```

and work with `newresponse` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to `encode` your `response` as `iso-8859-1` first and then `decode` (convert) it to `utf-8` before writing to a file opened as `utf-8`

```
response = u'temp\xc3\xaate'
r1 = response.encode('iso-8859-1')
r2 = r1.decode('utf-8')
```

Interesting read: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/