# What data type is this and how to convert it in readable format using python?

Tags: python, byte, data-conversion

I am retrieving data from an API and getting data like:

```
b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00%\x83\xa0\x08\x01\x00\xbb@\x00\x00\x05p \x02\x00>\xf3\x00\x00\x00}\x02\x00`\x03\xef0\x00\x00\r\xc0 \x06\xf0>\xf3\x00\x00\x02\x88\x02\x03\xec\x03\xef0\x00\x00/ '
```

When I checked data type in python, it's showing as bytes.I tried to convert it to readable format getting error as

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

What I tried:

[UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)

[error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)

[UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518023/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80-in-position-3131-invali)

Comment: What you have is a binary blob - it isn't human readable text.

Comment: What is this value supposed to represent? (i.e. what field is it from the API? what's the context here?)