# how to read the Azure blob file with Azure function in python?

Tags: python, audio, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am new in Azure cloud. Now I hope to create a work flow: upload a audio file to the blob --> Blob trigger is invoked --> deployed python function read the upload audio file and extract harmonics --> harmonics output as json file and save in another container. Blow is my code but it doesn't work:

```py
import logging
import azure.function as func
import audio_read

def main(myblob: func.InputStream):

    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
    
    audio_info = audioread.audio_open(myblob.read())
    logging.info(f"{audio_info}")
```

It returns me an error:

> Exception: UnicodeDecodeError: "utf-8" codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 40: invalid start byte.

my function.json is:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "examplecontainer/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518023/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80-in-position-3131-invali

Comment: Why when I run the code locally （audioread.audio_open("File saved path"), there is no error? However once I run on Azure Function (audioread.audio_open("inputblob"), it doesnt work. Is the way I feed blob wrong?

Comment: Make sure to upload your audio files as Blobs that contain binary data with proper ```content type``` and ```content encoding```, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.models.contentsettings?view=azure-python-previous)

Answer (score -1):

The input binding allows you to read blob storage data as input to an Azure Function.

For more details refer this document :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python

And make sure that you have given the proper content type and encoding  while uploading audio file as  blob in azure  storage

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.models.contentsettings?view=azure-python-previous)