# How to remove some bytes from a byte string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, byte

I am trying to remove a byte (`\x00\x81`) from a byte string `sByte`.

```py
sByte = b'\x00\x81308 921 q53 246 133 137 022 1   0 1 1  1 130 C13 330 0000000199 04002201\n'
```

I am expecting to have as a result the following:

```py
sByte = b'308 921 q53 246 133 137 022 1   0 1 1  1 130 C13 330 0000000199 04002201\n'
```

I have tried the following:

1. I tried to decode `sByte`; after running the below line of code,

   ```py
   sByte.decode('utf-8')
   ```

   I received a traceback: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1: invalid start byte`.
2. I also tried the following, but did not work:

   ```py
   sByte.replace('\x00\x81', '')
   ```
3. I also found this: 
   [json - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38534992/10543310)) but it did not help removing `\x00\x81`.

I am **not sure** how we can remove or replace a byte in byte string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bytes.replace` doesn't work in-place, it returns a modified copy of the `bytes` object. You can use `sByte = sByte.replace(b'\x00\x81', b'')` (or `bytes.removeprefix` if the bytes always occur at the start). Depending on your circumstances, you can also set the `errors` parameter of the `decode` method to `'ignore'`: `sByte = sByte.decode(encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')`.

Comment: Just as an "addition" to this answer, if OP wants to have a more "inclusive" substitute, they can always check out `re.sub`. For this specific answer it would be: `re.sub(b"\x00\x81", b'', sByte)`

Comment: @MichaelS. How does `re` behave differently in this case?

Comment: In this case, it does not, and `replace` is the better method. But if OP has other bytes that they want to remove with similar structures, then creating one `re.sub` that matches the format of all those other bytes could save them from doing a unique `replace` for each different byte. Again, in this case, your method is better. Just wanted OP to know about other options

Answer (score 3):

```py
>>> sByte = b'\x00\x81308 921 q53 246 133 137 022 1   0 1 1  1 130 C13 330 0000000199 04002201\n'
>>> sByte[2:]
b'308 921 q53 246 133 137 022 1   0 1 1  1 130 C13 330 0000000199 04002201\n'
```

See also https://appdividend.com/2022/07/09/python-slice-notation/

The code snippet returns `sByte` from and including the third byte until the end.

If you wanted to store the variable again you could do this:

```py
>>> sByte = b'\x00\x81308 921 q53 246 133 137 022 1   0 1 1  1 130 C13 330 0000000199 04002201\n'
>>> sByte = sByte[2:]
>>> sByte
b'308 921 q53 246 133 137 022 1   0 1 1  1 130 C13 330 0000000199 04002201\n'
```