# UnicodeEncodeError in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, locale

Some of my application's libraries are depending on being able to print UTF-8 characters to stdout and stderr. Therefore this must not fail:

```
print('\u2122')
```

On my local machine it works, but on my remote server it raises `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2122' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

I tried `$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` with no apparent effect.

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
```

works for a while, then stalls and finally fails with `ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached`

`sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `'utf-8'`, and `sys.stdout.encoding` returns `'ANSI_X3.4-1968'`

What can I do? I don't want to edit third-party libraries.

Comment: I think that [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python) is going to help you.

Comment: Side-note: Even if everything else worked, `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` won't work unless you `export` it (or prefix the Python launch with it). Otherwise, it's a local variable in `bash` that isn't inherited in the environment of child processes. `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` would both set and export it in `bash`.

Comment: @SamuelPS: The suggestion of the top answer there is... suboptimal. [Forcibly reloading `sys` to regain access to `setdefaultencoding` can cause problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3828742/364696), and in any event, the correct solution on modern Python (>=3.3) is to make sure your system is using a broadly useful full Unicode supporting default encoding globally. Anything else means you're using hacks to output characters the OS officially doesn't even recognize, and dependent on it playing along despite it claiming it won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From @ShadowRanger's comment on my question,

> `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` won't work unless you `export` it (or prefix the Python launch with it). Otherwise, it's a local variable in `bash` that isn't inherited in the environment of child processes. `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` would both set and export it in `bash`.

`export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` did the trick, UTF-8 characters no longer raise UnicodeEncodeError

Comment: Where to put this line export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 ? I read several similar questions and still cannot understand what file or script should i modify

Comment: @VicNicethemer run `export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` in bash before running `python your_script.py`

Comment: i have done that already, unfortunatelly this doesnot solve my case

Comment: it only works for stdout/in but not for fileIO, you need to set LC_CTYPE to utf-8 to handle everything

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're on a UNIX-like system, and your environment set `LANG` (or `LC_ALL` or whatever) to `C`.

Try editing your default shell's startup file to set `LANG` to something like `en_US.utf-8` (or whatever locale makes sense for you)? For example, in bash, edit `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile` if you're using that instead for `sh` compatibility) and add:

```
export LANG="en_US.utf-8"
```

For (t)csh, edit `~/.cshrc` (or `~/.tcshrc` if that's what you're using) to add:

```
setenv LANG "en_US.utf-8"
```

Making the changes "live" doesn't work, because your shell is likely hosted in a terminal that has configured itself solely for ASCII display, based on the `LANG=C` in effect when it was launched (and many terminals do session coalescence, so even if you changed `LANG` and then launched a new terminal, it would coalesce with the shared terminal process with the out-of-date `LANG`). So after you change `~/.bash_profile`, log out and then log back in so your root shell will set `LANG` correctly for every other process (since they all ultimately `fork` from the root shell).

Comment: `echo $LANG` is returning `en_US.UTF-8` by default

Comment: @Mirac7: That doesn't necessarily mean it was set that way at login. If you set it in your `.bashrc` for instance (and per normal setup, `.bashrc` isn't run for login shells), you'd see it in your terminals, but the terminals themselves wouldn't see it.