# Python - set encoding for scraping in many languages

Tags: python, encoding, web-scraping

While scraping web data, I am having `'ascii'` encoding issues such as:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 20-22: ordinal not in range(128)`,

and I came across this controversial solution which some say is dangerous:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

please see here:
[Why should we NOT use sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") in a py script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script)

I am using `Beautiful Soup`, and my app indexes text collected in different languages, such as german and french, besides english.

This is the snippet generating ocasional errors:

```
for page in pages:
                try:
                    c = urllib2.urlopen(page)
                except:
                    print "Could not open %s" % page
                    continue
                soup = BeautifulSoup(c.read())
```

traceback:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(c.read()) 
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1522, in __init__
    BeautifulStoneSoup.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1147, in __init__
    self._feed(isHTML=isHTML)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/BeautifulSoup.py", line 1189, in _feed
    SGMLParser.feed(self, markup)`

what is the safest way of scraping my data here without enconding issues?

Comment: maybe decode data to `utf-8` before you use in `BS` `c.read().decode('utf-8')` (if this page uses `utf-8`) because problem is in BS. As I know `sys.setdefaultencoding` works with `print()` problems.

Comment: Or use `requests` module which can find encoding used on page and gives decoded string in `r.text` (or not-decoded bytes in `r.content`)