# Python: sys prevents print of elements

Tags: python-2.7, sys

In Python 2.7 I have the following and I debug through IDLE:

```
print 'Here'
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('cp1252')
print 'There'
```

what I get in return is

> Here

So after I have set the default encoding it does not print the desired output.
Could this be due by conflicts with the IDLE encoding?

Comment: Why are you doing a `reload(sys)`?

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this?

Comment: I am using reload because I read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python

I want to change my encoding to cp1252 but if I follow the process in the link above it does not print anything else

Answer (score 2):

Because it is unable to find reference to setdefaultencoding from sys. That is why it is not printing ***'There'***

setdefaultencoding is deprecated and one should never use it!

Have a look at the following link.
[Why should we NOT use sys.setdefaultencoding(“utf-8”) in a py script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script) is also some pretty good advice

Comment: Ok because I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python

Is there a way to change the encoding from Python itself so that If I forward my code to a friend he is able to run it with changed charset (cp1252)

Comment: It's a trick to change default encoding using reload(sys) but it is never recommended as per the documentation!