# How to encode string into utf-8 for both Python 2.x and 3.x

Tags: python, encode

I'm trying to write a formatted string containing Cyrillic symbols (in utf-8) to Unix pipe:

```
sort_proc.stdin.write("{}\n".format(cyrillic_text).decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8'))
```

I had to encode because `'str' does not support the buffer interface` and decode because `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0`. So this code works in Python 2.7 as expected. However Python 3.4 says `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` as string literals in python3 are already "decoded". So I know how to fix it for each version separately but don't know how to fix for both. I've found a solution related to reloading sys module and setting setdefaultencoding, however this article [why should we NOT use sys.setdefaultencoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script) says it's just a hack and shouldn't be used at all. Please post the most pythonic way of doing these things. Thanks.

Comment: You can execute different code depending on the version: `if sys.version_info[0]==2: .... else: ....`

Comment: What does `.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')` achieve? Doesn't look very meaningful.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think encode without decode uses default ascii codec, that's why it can't decode `0xd0`. In general it works without encode in python2 but doesn't work in python3

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I don't understand. What is `"{}\n".format(cyrillic_text)`? Can you give a small example? I.e., some `s` so that `s.decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')` isn't the same as `s`?

Comment: Where does `cyrillic_text` come from?  Is a string literal?  User input?  Text read from a file?

Comment: it comes from a text file with data encoded in utf-8

Comment: I managed to get Unicode data from the file using `codecs.open("path", "r", encoding='utf-8')`, but it failes down the road in third party modules on `b'utf string'.split('python3 unicode separator')` line,  so I have to use @DYZ's solution for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unicode` strings](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) (instead of the 8-bit `str`) throughout your Python 2.x code.  This is equivalent to Python 3.x `str` type.  Then, you can simply use `the_string.encode('UTF-8')` to get byte string (of type `str` in 2.x, but `bytes` in 3.x).

If you don't need to support Python 3.0 through 3.2, you can prefix all your string literals with `u`.  In Python 2.x, this creates a `unicode` string, and in 3.3+ [it's supported for backwards compatibility](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/) but does nothing.