# (Python 2.7)How to solve :UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, unicode

here is my question :

```
    if not line.startswith('  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried the method :

```
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

but it seems that it didn't work on the version 2.7

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You would benefit from learning about string encoding.
That said, there's something in Python 2.7 which solves these problems most of the time.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

This has to be the first statement in your Python module. It will change the data types of all strings in the module to Unicode.

Be careful and read about [pros and cons](http://python-future.org/unicode_literals.html).
Generally speaking, you will be fine if you are starting a new project, but introducing this change in existing (especially big) project can be a hard and time consuming task.

One more thing - when starting a new Python project now, you should really consider doing it in Python 3. The end of life of for Python 2.7 [has been moved to 2020](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/) but it's just 2 years from now. Python 3 has many interesting features and improvements. What you will find important is that `str` is Unicode in Python 3 - it means that encoding problems don't happen so often.