# Python 3.6 utf-8 UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-3.6

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filenames = glob.glob("C:\\Users\\####\\Desktop\\BNC2\\[A00-ZZZ]*.xml")
out_lines = []
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as content:
        tree = ET.parse(content)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for w in root.iter('w'):
            lemma = w.get('hw')
            pos = w.get('pos')
            tag = w.get('c5')

            out_lines.append(w.text + "," + lemma + "," + pos + "," + tag)

with open("C:\\Users\\####\\Desktop\\bnc.txt", "w") as out_file:
    for line in out_lines:
        line = bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
        out_file.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

Gives the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2192' in position 0: character maps to undefined
```

I thought this line would have solved that:

```py
line = bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
```

Comment: Have you tried `open("C:\\Users\\####\\Desktop\\bnc.txt", "w", encoding='utf8')` ??

Comment: Please post the entire traceback. Python told you what line had the problem... pay it forward! Don't make us guess.

Comment: All `line = bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore')` did was encode in utf-8 and decode again. You get the original string back. The problem I suspect is when you try to write to the ascii file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the encoding when opening the output file, same as you did with the input file:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\####\\Desktop\\bnc.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as out_file:
    for line in out_lines:
        out_file.write("{}\n".format(line))
```

Answer (score -2):

If your script have multiple reads and writes and you want to have a particular encoding ( let's say utf-8) for all of them, we can change the default encoding too

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

We should use it only when we have multiple reads/writes though and should be done at the beginning of the script

[Changing default encoding of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)

Comment: This doesn't work. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script). Its so bad that `setdefaultencoding` has been disappeared. You won't find it in 3.6 unless you do some hacky stuff.

Comment: Yes, but when i have to reading to do, i have used it sometimes. Have not tried it with Python 3.6 though

Comment: Changing the default is bad. It breaks other modules that expect the default to be "the default".  That's why the function doesn't work  unless you do the reload "trick".  Just open the file with the correct encoding!