# What's the different between "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" ，"from __future__ import unicode_literals" and "sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")"

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8

**What I know is:**

1. `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
   It is used to declare the encoding of a Python source file, once I set the encoding name, Python parser will interpret the file using the given encoding. I call it "**file encoding**";
2. `from __future__ import unicode_literals` 
   I'm doing my tasks using Python2.7, and I use `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to change the default type of string from "str" to "unicode". I call it "**string encoding**";
3. `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')`
   But sometimes, I get an error in Django, for example, I stored Chinese in admin, then I visited the releated pages

   > UnicodeEncodeError at /admin/blog/vulpaper/29/change/
   >   'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-13: ordinal not in range(128)
   >   ....the more error information
   >   The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: emcms外贸网站管理系统

   for this problem, I will write `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` in Django settings file to solve it.

*But Actually, I don't know the tech detail of the above.*

**What make me confused is:**
1. Since I set the python source file encoding, why should I set the string encoding to ensure my string's encoding is my favorite encoding?
What's the different between "file encoding" and "string encoding"?
2. Since I set the "file encoding" and "string encoding", why do UnicodeEncodeError still happen?

Comment: Because the encoding of the python source code file, and how Python will encode strings itself are two different things. You can construct a python file in utf-8, but write ASCII strings.

Comment: Setting `sys.setdefaultencoding` is unlikely to be the right answer to anything. If you're getting that error, you probably have a mistake in your `__unicode__` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thx, you mentioned me, I search the related question and found that almost no one recommend newbie to use `sys.setdefaultencoding` in projects, so I remove it from my settings' file. First I check the Chinese string data type what I ready to store, it's unicode, then I check the model, when I change the instance methods from `__str__` to `__unicode__`, it works! I avoid the UnicodeEncodeError

Answer (score 2):

Usually you have to use both `file encoding` and `literal strings encoding` but they actually control something **very different** and it is helpful to know the difference.

### File Encoding

If you expect to write unicode characters in your source code in any place like comments or literal strings, you **need** to change the encoding in order for the python parser to work. Setting the wrong encoding will result in `SyntaxError` exception. [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) explains the problem in detail and how you can control the encoding of the parser.

> In Python 2.1, Unicode literals can only be written using the Latin-1
>   based encoding "unicode-escape". This makes the programming
>   environment rather unfriendly to Python users who live and work in
>   non-Latin-1 locales such as many of the Asian countries.
>
> ...
>
> Python will default to ASCII as standard encoding if no other encoding hints are given.

### Unicode Literal Strings

Python 2 uses two different types for strings, `unicode` and `str`. When you define a literal string the interpreter actually creates a new object of type `str` that holds this literal.

```
s = "A literal string"
print type(s)

<type 'str'>
```

> TL;DR
>
> If you want to change this behavior and instead create `unicode` object every time an unprefixed string literal is defined, you can use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

If you need to understand why this is useful keep reading.

You can explicitly define a literal string as unicode using the `u` prefix. The interpreter will create instead a `unicode` object for this literal.

```
s = u"A literal string"
print type(s)

<type 'unicode'>
```

For ASCII text, using `str` type is sufficient but if you intend to manipulate non-ASCII text it is **important** to use `unicode` type for character level operations to work correctly. The following example shows the difference of character level interpretation using `str` and `unicode` for exactly the same literal.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def print_characters(s):
    print "String of type {}".format(type(s))
    print "  Length: {} ".format(len(s))
    print "  Characters: " ,
    for c in s:
        print c,
    print
    print


u_lit = u"Γειά σου κόσμε"
s_lit = "Γειά σου κόσμε"

print_characters(u_lit)
print_characters(s_lit)
```

Output:

```
String of type <type 'unicode'>
  Length: 14 
  Characters:  Γ ε ι ά   σ ο υ   κ ό σ μ ε

String of type <type 'str'>
  Length: 26 
  Characters:  � � � � � � � �   � � � � � �   � � � � � � � � � �
```

Using `str` it erroneously reported that it is of `26` characters length and iterating over character returned garbage. On the other hand `unicode` worked as expected.

### Setting sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

There is a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script) in stack overflow about why we shouldn't use it :)