# How to solve UnicodeDecodeError in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, unicode

I am switched from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6.

I have scripts that deal with some non-English content.

I usually run scripts via Cron and also in Terminal.

I had UnicodeDecodeError in my Python 2.7 scripts and I solved by this.

```
# encoding=utf8  
import sys  

reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Now in Python 3.6, it doesnt work. I have print statements like `print("Here %s" % (myvar))` and it throws error. I can solve this issue by replacing it to `myvar.encode("utf-8")` but I don't want to write with each print statement.

I did `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8` in my terminal and I have still that issue.

Is there a cleaner way to solve `UnicodeDecodeError` issue in Python 3.6?

is there any way to tell Python3 to print everything in utf-8? just like I did in Python2?

Comment: Are the non-English files encoded properly in UTF-8 themselves?

Comment: @EdwardMinnix I am scraping data from various Hewbrew/Korean sites, so data is not always clean.

Comment: @usr2564301 is there any way to tell Python3 to print everything in utf-8? just like I did in Python2?

Comment: Normally your terminal has an encoding defined which is used by Python to set the encoding of its file object (`sys.stdout`).  Can you provide what `sys.stdout.encoding` is set to on your machine?

Comment: @Alfe `ANSI_X3.4-1968`

Comment: @Alfe just checked, my Python2 and Python3 both has `ANSI_X3.4-1968`

Comment: @usr2564301 so I will have to do `.encode("utf-8")` in every print statement

Comment: I think that is the root of the problem.  What strange terminal are you using?  In Unix-ish environments you can set the env var `TERM` to something like `xterm` or similar.  Also the `LANG` variable could have an influence.

Comment: @Alfe its a Ubuntu server and I am connected to it via MobaXterm

Comment: Maybe this MobaXterm is configured strangely and can be improved.

Comment: What is the result of `echo $LANG` ?

Comment: Yet another reason for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script/34378962#34378962

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack `echo $LANG` is empty

Comment: @Umair bingo - that's at least the start of your problem. Your operating system should be setting this for you. Please check your system is setup correctly

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack now I did `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` and ran script, but still same error, (not a linux expert here)

Comment: @umair did you do `export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack yeah i did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173761/discussion-between-alastair-mccormack-and-umair).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It sounds like your locale is broken **and have another bytes->Unicode issue**. The thing you did for Python 2.7 is a hack that only masked the real problem (there's a reason why you have to `reload sys` to make it work).

To fix your locale, try typing `locale` from the command line. It should look something like:

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

`locale` depends on `LANG` being set properly. Python effectively uses `locale` to work out what encoding to use when writing to stdout in. If it can't work it out, it defaults to ASCII.

**You should first attempt to fix your locale. If `locale` errors, make sure you've installed the correct language pack for your region.**

If all else fails, you can always fix Python by setting `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8`. This should be used as a last resort as you'll be masking problems once again.

If Python is still throwing an error after setting `PYTHONIOENCODING` then please update your question with the stacktrace. Chances are you've got an implied conversion going on.

Comment: For future readers, please see our conversation in chat how @Alastair McCormack helped me solve my problem. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173761/discussion-between-alastair-mccormack-and-umair

Comment: thanks for the answer and the discussion in the chat, It really helped me.
I was facing a similar error in doing print('\u25cf') in python3. Setting the locale to en_US.utf8 helped.

Comment: Thanks! When I type `locale` it tuned out that all values are "POSIX"...

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue when using Python inside a Docker container based on Ubuntu 18.04.
It appeared to be a locale issue, which was solved by adding the following to the Dockerfile:

```
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```

Comment: `export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` before running python in console fix this temporarily

Answer (score 4):

To everyone using *pickle* to load a file previously saved in python 2 and getting an UnicodeDecodeError, try setting pickle `encoding` parameter:

```
with open("./data.pkl", "rb") as data_file:
    samples = pickle.load(data_file, encoding='latin1')
```

Answer (score 1):

For a Python-only solution you will have to recreate your `sys.stdout` object:

```
import sys, codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout.detach())
```

After this, a normal `print("hello world")` should be encoded to UTF-8 automatically.

But you should try to find out why your terminal is set to such a strange encoding (which Python just tries to adopt to).  Maybe your operating system is configured wrong somehow.

EDIT: In my tests unsetting the env variable `LANG` produced this strange setting for the stdout encoding for me:

```
LANG= python3
import sys
sys.stdout.encoding
```

printed `'ANSI_X3.4-1968'`.

So I guess you might want to set your `LANG` to something like 
`en_US.UTF-8`.  Your terminal program doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: Is this the same or significantly different from `sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')`? (Which I am sure I have learned from this very website.)

Comment: @usr2564301 I'm not sure about the difference (if any).  The idea is clearly the same.  A much nicer way would be the simple `sys.stdout.encoding = 'utf-8'` but that doesn't work, unfortunately, because the `encoding` field is readonly.  But this is always the father of the thought and the two solutions are just different workaround implementations of it.

Answer (score -1):

Python 3 (including 3.6) is already Unicode supported. Here is the doc - https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

So you don't need to force Unicode support like Python 2.7. Try to run your code normally. If you get any error reading a Unicode text file you need to use the `encoding='utf-8'` parameter while reading the file.

Answer (score -1):

for docker with python3.6, use `LANG=C.UTF-8 python or jupyter xxx` works for me, thanks to @Daniel and @zhy

Answer (score -3):

I mean you could write an custom function like this:
(Not optimal i know)

---

```
import sys

def printUTF8(input):
    print(input.encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: any way without doing `.encode("utf-8")`? so Python knows to print every string in utf-8?