# Why did I get UnicodeDecodeError when I read a file which contains Chinese characters?

Tags: python, encoding

```
>>> path = 'name.txt'
>>> content = None
>>> with open(path, 'r') as file:
...     content = file.readlines()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/mnt/lustre/share/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 163: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I run this code to read a file which contains Chinese characters, I got an error. The file is saved by using UTF-8. My python version is 3.6.5. But it runs ok in python2.7.

Comment: [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: open can take an optional "encoding" keyword in python3 ... in python 2 it would implicitly try to decode it for you ... most of the time it got it right ...

Comment: `with open(path, 'rb')` not r

Comment: Did you read the error message? `'ascii' codec` ... You need to tell it to use UTF-8.

Comment: @sinafarhadi No, that would open it as binary. OP wants to read UTF-8.

Comment: @Joran Python 2's `open()` doesn't decode.  It just returns byte strings.  You may be thinking of `codecs.open()` or `io.open()`.

Comment: @sinafarhadi `rb` can open it without errors, but it unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is using the ASCII codec to try to read the file. The easiest way to fix this is to specify the encoding:

```
with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
```

Your [locale should probably specify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51027262/4518341) the [preferred encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding) as UTF-8, but I think it depends on OS and language settings.

Comment: I can read the file without errors by using this. But when I try `print (content[0])`, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 reads files into byte strings by default.

Python 3.x reads files into Unicode strings by default, so the bytes in the file must be decoded.

The default encoding used varies by operating system, but can be determined by calling `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`.  This is often `utf8` on Linux systems, but Windows systems return a localized ANSI encoding, e.g. `cp1252` for US/Western European Windows versions.

In Python 3, specify the encoding you expect for files so as not to rely on a locale-specific default.  For example:

```
with open(path,'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    ...
```

You can do this in Python 2 as well, but use `io.open()`, which is compatible with Python 3's `open()` and will read Unicode strings instead of byte strings.  `io.open()` is available in Python 3 as well for portability.