# How to split a file containing many records into smaller groups of records

Tags: python, linux, bash, split

How to split a file containing many records, as below, into smaller files, each of them containing a smaller number of records ?

```
<TAG>
Record_1
</TAG>
<TAG>
Record_2
</TAG>
<TAG>
Record_3
</TAG>
<TAG>
Record_4
</TAG>
<TAG>
Record_5
</TAG>
```

Of course we talk about very large numbers.
The goal is to split this file into smaller ones, but not with one record per file as we often see using `csplit`. Here we want, for instance, 2 records per file (but could be 100 or more).

So the expected result would be:

`split1`

```
<TAG>
Record_1
</TAG>
<TAG>
Record_2
</TAG>
```

`split2`

```
<TAG>
Record_3
</TAG>
<TAG>
Record_4
</TAG>
```

`split3`

```
<TAG>
Record_5
</TAG>
```

If not possible using standard command line, I may consider writing a few lines of python for instance, but I am not familiar with it.
Is there an easy solution to this pretty simple task ?

Comment: open file, read 10 tags, write 10 tags into new file, iterate until done. What is the exact problem/question?

Comment: I am not familiar with python so if it's the best/only option, I would love an example :)

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post. SO is not providing you with working code foryour problems, thats not how SO works. See [ask], read tutorials, try your best. If you have a specific problem with _your_ code post a [mre] with a specific answerable question.

Comment: well, the question is pretty clear, the expected result also, I don't know much the bash commands allowing to do it, if any, so I ask the community. the accepted approachs are: simplest as possible, using few lines of code if required. so everything is clear to me.

Comment: There is a class of questions on Stack Overflow about **small text-processing problems** which ask for a solution of this problem in a scripting language supported by any of the "standard" Linux utilities. If such question has an answer(s) with short (preferably one-line) solutions, the question becomes **well-received**. But if there is no short solution, the value of the question asked for many languages at once is quite **low**. Unfortunately, before the "nice" answer is posted, it is difficult to categorize the question. But I feel that given question **could** have a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had to play with python myself.
Here is an easy and reusable solution (could certainly be improved but it works well).

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, re, argparse

# config
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Split file into smaller ones, each one containing N blocs delimited by regexp')
parser.add_argument('inputf', metavar='FILE', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                    help='the input file to split')
parser.add_argument('regexp', metavar='REGEXP',
                    help='the regular expression matching start of a new bloc')
parser.add_argument('--repeat', type=int, default=1, metavar='N',
                    help='the number of blocs to add per file')
parser.add_argument('--prefix', default='split_',
                    help='the prefix of generated files')
parser.add_argument('--suffix', default='.txt',
                    help='the suffix of generated files')
args = parser.parse_args()

# function
def split_file(fdin, regexp, repeat=1, prefix='split_', suffix='.txt'):
    nFile=0
    nMatch=0

    # Read file line by line
    for i, line in enumerate(fdin):
        # Check if regexp match
        if re.match(regexp, line):
            nMatch+=1

        # Increase file suffix
        if ( nMatch >= repeat ):
            nFile+=1
            nMatch=0

        # Write lines to file
        with open(f"{prefix}{nFile:03}{suffix}", "a") as fdout:
            fdout.write(line)

# run
split_file(args.inputf, args.regexp, args.repeat, args.prefix, args.suffix)
```

Usage is pretty simple as described by `argparse`.

```
./split.py -h
usage: split.py [-h] [--repeat REPEAT] [--prefix PREFIX] [--suffix SUFFIX]
                FILE REGEXP

Split file into smaller ones, each one containing N blocs delimited by regexp

positional arguments:
  FILE             the input file to split
  REGEXP           the regular expression matching start of a new bloc

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  --repeat N       the number of blocs to add per file
  --prefix PREFIX  the prefix of generated files
  --suffix SUFFIX  the suffix of generated files
```

So the answer to the given example would be:
`./split.py input.xml '<TAG>' --repeat 2`

Note that input file can also be stdin if `-` is supplied in place of file.

Enjoy if you find this!

Comment: Thanks., But I think with my `UTF8` File I have Problem. I get the following error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1768: character maps to <undefined>` What can I do? THANKS

Comment: on WSL I also get this ERROR `File "/usr/lib/python3.10/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 4408: invalid start byte`

Comment: I think this error is related to Python 3, while this script was written for Python 2. Please look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026315/how-to-solve-unicodedecodeerror-in-python-3-6