# Python pyperclip cannot copy decoded

Tags: python, string, utf-8, decode, pyperclip

I just found out that for some reason when copying using pyperclip a string that was decoded (using utf-8), it will raise an error.

```
import pyperclip
with open('chat.txt' 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()
# the string is encoded in utf-8 in order to be able to write down `'`, `emoji` and other special signs or symbol
pyperclip.copy(string.decode('utf-8'))
```

It will raise this error: `PyperclipException: only str, int, float, and bool values can be copied to the clipboard, not unicode`

I found a roundabout way to solve it by using `str()` but then found out that it won't work since `str()` does not work if there are some character like `'`.

---

**EDIT: Alternative solution**

An alternative solution except for the solution that I accepted would be degrade the *pyperclip* from the newest version (right now its `1.6.4`) to a lower version (`1.6.1` worked for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be facing some issues with non-ASCII quotation marks. I suggest you to use Python 3.7. Here's a sample:

```
import pyperclip

with open('chat.txt', 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()
pyperclip.copy(string)
```

This is an alternative for Python 2.7:

```
import pyperclip
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

with open('chat.txt', 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()

pyperclip.copy(string)
```

**Warning: As pointed out in a comment by @lenz the use of `sys.setdefaultencoding()` is a hack and discouraged for a [number of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script).**

Comment: Well another issue is that I get the string from a file and I don't know where the ' is and whether other character will pose issue or not...

Comment: You need to provide more details on how you are retrieving the string from the file.

Comment: Your question isn't clear but I guess I could reproduce your issue. I've just edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I just edit my code to be more clear but you pretty much reproduced my issue. Is there any other way than switching to python 3 because I would have to convert my whole python 2.7 code to python 3.

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner I suggest you upgrade to Python 3 anyway. You'll have to sooner or later. The `2to3` tool (part of the Python installation) does a very good job at helping you port the code.

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner I just edited the answer again with an alternative code for Python 2. Anyway, it should be a good opportunity to you move to Python 3.

Comment: @xilopaint Using `sys.setdefaultencoding` is a hack that shouldn't be used (that's why you have to `reload(sys)` to make it work). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script) for some reasons why.

Comment: @ProgramerBeginner Does this answer address your question?

Comment: @xilopaint Oh sorry, I forgot to mark it as answered. Yes it kind of answer my questions, though I at the end choose to degrade pyperclip to version `1.6.1`, which for some reason worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been fixed in 1.6.5, so all you have to do is update pyperclip by running `pip install -U pyperclip`.