# Invalid continuation byte error while reading csv file

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a csv file using python on jupyter notebook using the following command:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("/Users/noha/Desktop/SongCSV.csv")
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 5: invalid continuation byte

I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: There's invalid encoding in the file.

Comment: Can you post csv file too ?

Comment: Your CSV file is not UTF-8. What program did you create it with? If it was a program like Excel on Windows, CP-1252 is a reasonable encoding to try. But fundamentally you need to know the encoding before you can read *any* text file, whether CSV or anything else.

Comment: Please, see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54455487/python-failure-on-output-redirect-pipe/54455794#54455794
I think it may be useful.

Answer (score -1):

If you mention the encoding it will be solve:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('/Users/noha/Desktop/SongCSV.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

If face any problem comment below

Comment: The error message indicates that it's already using the `utf-8` codec.

Comment: Then has to check its encoding system.. does your csv file opensource? Then I can find out the solutions by test it on my pc