# Web scraping python error (NameError: name 'reload' is not defined)

Tags: python, web-scraping

Trying to do some web scraping with python and getting an error.

I am not sure what this trackback error means, I am running it in Python3, can anyone help?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/WebScraping/GoodreadsScraper.py", line 3, in 
    reload(sys)
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
#from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
import csv
import time
import json

class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, url):
        self.title = title
        self.url = url
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.title, self.url])

url = 'https://www.goodreads.com/'

def create_csv_file():
    header = ['Title', 'URL']
    with open('/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv', 'w+') as csv_file:
        wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        wr.writerow(header)

def read_from_txt_file():
    lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/BookTitles.txt')]
    return lines

def init_selenium():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.get('https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=')

def search_for_title(title):
    search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search_query_main"]')
    search_field.clear()
    search_field.send_keys(title)
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input[3]')
    search_button.click()

def scrape_url():
    try:
        url = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.bookTitle').get_attribute('href')
    except:
        url = "N/A"

    return url

def write_into_csv_file(vendor):
    with open('/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        wr.writerow(list(vendor))

create_csv_file()
titles = read_from_txt_file()    
init_selenium()

for title in titles:
    search_for_title(title)
    url = scrape_url()
    book = Book(title, url)
    write_into_csv_file(book)
```

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: I'm shutting down for the night. Useful information is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script

Comment: Not sure if it is 2 or 3, how can I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reload is not supported in Python3 anymore

You should remove these lines

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Instead you should pass `encoding='utf-8'` as arguement when open file in Python3.x

Line no 29:

```
with open('/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv', 'w+') as csv_file:
```

changes to

```
with open('/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
```

Line no 34:

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/BookTitles.txt')]
```

changes to

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/BookTitles.txt', encoding='utf-8')]
```

Line no 62:

```
with open('/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
```

changes to

```
with open('/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but still got the same error, Im going to try and repost

Comment: Edited my answer. You should also remove first 3 lines.

Comment: Thank you but am still getting an error: NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: I posted a similar question here with you updated changes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763873/web-scraping-with-python-getting-an-error