# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128) with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter, ascii

I have a ploblem when i test data mining from twitter by i search data by word.

It error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)` from this code

```
retweet = "-filter:retweets"
query = "#Thailand" + retweet 

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["create_at","user","location","text", "retweet_count", "favourite_count","hashtag","follower","source"])
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q = query,result_type="recent", tweet_mode='extended').items(100):
     
    entity_hashtag = tweet.entities.get('hashtags')
    hashtag = ""
    for i in range(0, len(entity_hashtag)):
        hashtag = hashtag + "/" + entity_hashtag[i]["text"]
    re_count = tweet.retweet_count
    create_at = tweet.created_at
    user = tweet.user.screen_name
    source = tweet.source
    location = tweet.user.location
    follower = tweet.user.followers_count

    try:
        text = tweet.retweeted_status.full_text
        fav_count = tweet.retweeted_status.favorite_count 

    except:     
        text = tweet.full_text
        fav_count = tweet.favorite_count  
    new_column = pd.Series([create_at,user,location,text, re_count, fav_count,hashtag,follower,source], index = df.columns)
    df = df.append(new_column, ignore_index = True)

df.to_csv(date_time+".csv")
```

Why have this ploblem ?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: which lines makes proble ? Add it in question (not in comment)

Comment: usually problem is that text has some native chars but system try to convert it to `ascii` instead of `utf-8`, `latin1` or `cp1250` and you have to manually add this options (ie. `encode="utf-8"`) if it possible to function which makes problem.

Comment: I think ploblem this df.to_csv(date_time+".csv")

Comment: better show full error message

Comment: if you think problem is `to_csv()` then find documentation for `to_csv()` and check if it has option for setting `utf-8` or `latin1` or `cp1250`

Comment: File "wu.py", line 46, in <module>
    df.to_csv(date_time+".csv")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3020, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 172, in save
    self._save()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 288, in _save

Comment: did you read previous comments - always put error message in QUESTION, not in comment. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: error shows you problem with `to_csv()` so now find documentation for `to_csv()` to see all available options. It should have code `encode` or `encoding` or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the system default encoding as `utf-8` at the start of your scipt, the following should set the default encoding as utf-8 .

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: It's work Thank you.

Comment: @ArifeenKundee Please accept my answer by clicking on tick mark. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of Python you are using but I would look in Python's documentation on the subject here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ (for Python 2)

From there:

To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must be placed into the source files either as first or second line in the file, such as:

```
# coding=<encoding name>
```

or (using formats recognized by popular editors):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
```

or:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# vim: set fileencoding=<encoding name> :
```

I have used this version in certain cases:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: <encoding name> -*-
```

That said, some functions, and especially `str()` should not be used with unicode. Prefer `unicode()` instead. When using third party libraries you will have to check their documentation, and possibly look at their source if their docs are limited.

Comment: Also, take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828723/why-should-we-not-use-sys-setdefaultencodingutf-8-in-a-py-script which discourages the use of setdefaultencoding.

Comment: You probably just need to export PYTHONIOENCODING="UTF-8" in your shell.