# Usage of unicode() and encode() functions in Python

Tags: python, string, sqlite, unicode, encoding

I have a problem with encoding of the *path* variable and inserting it to the *SQLite* database. I tried to solve it with *encode("utf-8")* function which didn't help. Then I used `unicode()` function which gives me type *unicode*.

```
print type(path)                  # <type 'unicode'>
path = path.replace("one", "two") # <type 'str'>
path = path.encode("utf-8")       # <type 'str'> strange
path = unicode(path)              # <type 'unicode'>
```

Finally I gained *unicode* type, but I still have the same error which was present when the type of the *path* variable was *str*

> sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless
> you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like
> text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just
> switch your application to Unicode strings.

Could you help me solve this error and explain the correct usage of `encode("utf-8")` and `unicode()` functions? I'm often fighting with it.

This `execute()` statement raised the error:

```
cur.execute("update docs set path = :fullFilePath where path = :path", locals())
```

I forgot to change the encoding of `fullFilePath` variable which suffers with the same problem, but I'm quite confused now. Should I use only `unicode()` or `encode("utf-8")` or both?

I can't use

```
fullFilePath = unicode(fullFilePath.encode("utf-8"))
```

because it raises this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position
> 32: ordinal not in range(128)

*Python* version is *2.7.2*

Comment: Your exact question has already been answered: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392732/sqlite-python-unicode-and-non-utf-data][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392732/sqlite-python-unicode-and-non-utf-data

Comment: have you converted both used variables to `unicode`?

Comment: Learning how Python 3 [handles](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit) text and data has really helped me understand everything. It is then easy to apply the knowledge to Python 2.

Comment: here is the slides of a great talk about unicode in python -- [link](http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/)

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You are using `encode("utf-8")` incorrectly.  Python byte strings (`str` type) have an encoding, Unicode does not.  You can convert a Unicode string to a Python byte string using `uni.encode(encoding)`, and you can convert a byte string to a Unicode string using `s.decode(encoding)` (or equivalently, `unicode(s, encoding)`).

If `fullFilePath` and `path` are currently a `str` type, you should figure out how they are encoded.  For example, if the current encoding is utf-8, you would use:

```
path = path.decode('utf-8')
fullFilePath = fullFilePath.decode('utf-8')
```

If this doesn't fix it, the actual issue may be that you are not using a Unicode string in your `execute()` call, try changing it to the following:

```
cur.execute(u"update docs set path = :fullFilePath where path = :path", locals())
```

Comment: This statement `fullFilePath = fullFilePath.decode("utf-8")` still raises error `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 32-34: ordinal not in range(128)`. fullFilePath is a combination of type *str* and string taken from *text* column of db table which should be utf-8 encoding.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) but it can be UTF-8, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE. Can I find out it somehow?

Comment: @xralf, If you are combining different `str` objects you may be mixing encodings.  Can you show the result of `print repr(fullFilePath)`?

Comment: I can show it only before the call of *decode()*. The problematic characters are \u0161 and \u0165.

Comment: @xralf - So it is already unicode?  Try changing the execute call to unicode: `cur.execute(u"update docs set path = :fullFilePath where path = :path", locals())`

Answer (score 135):

`str` is text representation in bytes, `unicode` is text representation in characters.

You decode text from bytes to unicode and encode a unicode into bytes with some encoding.

That is:

```
>>> 'abc'.decode('utf-8')  # str to unicode
u'abc'
>>> u'abc'.encode('utf-8') # unicode to str
'abc'
```

*UPD Sep 2020*: The answer was written when Python 2 was mostly used. In Python 3, `str` was renamed to `bytes`, and `unicode` was renamed to `str`.

```
>>> b'abc'.decode('utf-8') # bytes to str
'abc'
>>> 'abc'.encode('utf-8'). # str to bytes
b'abc'
```

Comment: Very good answer, straight to the point. I'd add that `unicode` speaks about letters or symbols, or more generically: **runes** while `str` represents a bytes string in a certain encoding, that you must `decode` (obviously in the correct encoding) to get the specific runes

Comment: Python 3.8 >> `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: do you have documentation for change unicode to str? I cant find

Comment: @cikatomo It's one one of the key changes in Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've set your locale settings right before running the script from the shell, e.g.

```
$ locale -a | grep "^en_.\+UTF-8"
en_GB.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8
$ export LC_ALL=en_GB.UTF-8
$ export LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Docs: `man locale`, `man setlocale`.