# Why am I getting a u letter for each element's name in a python set?

Tags: python, twitter, set

I'm doing tests for python's twitter library using Twitter API, I requested all trending topics for a specific WOEID, called this **`mexican_trends`**.

Then I tried to get every specific trend name in a set, tried this way:

```
trendsSet = set(trend['name']
            for trend in mexican_trends[0]['trends'])
```

But `print` dumps a *u* letter as prefix for every element in `trendSet`.

This is the `print json.dumps(mexican_trends, indent=2)`

```
[   {
    "created_at": "2014-01-17T18:51:20Z", 
    "trends": [
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23MentirasQueNoTienenPerdon", 
        "query": "%23MentirasQueNoTienenPerdon", 
        "name": "#MentirasQueNoTienenPerdon", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }, 
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23FelizCumpleJLRoma", 
        "query": "%23FelizCumpleJLRoma", 
        "name": "#FelizCumpleJLRoma", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }, 
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23EsDeChakas", 
        "query": "%23EsDeChakas", 
        "name": "#EsDeChakas", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }, 
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Jos%C3%A9+Sulaim%C3%A1n%22", 
        "query": "%22Jos%C3%A9+Sulaim%C3%A1n%22", 
        "name": "Jos\u00e9 Sulaim\u00e1n", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }, 
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23RioRomaEnRitmoson", 
        "query": "%23RioRomaEnRitmoson", 
        "name": "#RioRomaEnRitmoson", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }, 
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%23TemasPerfectos", 
        "query": "%23TemasPerfectos", 
        "name": "#TemasPerfectos", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }, 
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=%22Juan+Gelman%22", 
        "query": "%22Juan+Gelman%22", 
        "name": "Juan Gelman", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }, 
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=Michoac%C3%A1n", 
        "query": "Michoac%C3%A1n", 
        "name": "Michoac\u00e1n", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }, 
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=M%C3%A9xico", 
        "query": "M%C3%A9xico", 
        "name": "M\u00e9xico", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }, 
      {
        "url": "http://twitter.com/search?q=TLCAN", 
        "query": "TLCAN", 
        "name": "TLCAN", 
        "promoted_content": null, 
        "events": null
      }
    ], 
    "as_of": "2014-01-17T18:59:14Z", 
    "locations": [
      {
        "woeid": 23424900, 
        "name": "Mexico"
      }
    ]   
  } 
]
```

And `trendsSet` is printed as:

```
set([u'#RioRomaEnRitmoson', u'M\xe9xico', u'#MentirasQueNoTienenPerdon', u'TLCAN', u'#EsDeChakas', u'#FelizCumpleJLRoma', u'Juan Gelman', u'#TemasPerfectos', u'Jos\xe9 Sulaim\xe1n', u'Michoac\xe1n'])
```

As said, uith u letters as prefix for each element, why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599625/python-string-prints-as-ustring

Comment: Shit, that is right. I actually looked up for u in python arrays but got not results at first glance ... As mexican_trends is actually a list.

Comment: @Wooble: Vote to close as a dup instead of just posting a comment. That gives more information to the OP, prevents hundreds of dups showing up in searches for future users, etc.

Comment: @abarnert: I ran out of close votes for the day hours ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'u' character preceding the string indicates that the string is a unicode string. The python docs at http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html and other questions on stack exchange such as [Usage of unicode() and encode() functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288016/usage-of-unicode-and-encode-functions-in-python) can help you if you have specific uses in mind, or need to operate with them.

Answer (score 1):

The u means that the string is in Unicode.