# Django + sqlite + Unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

I faced a problem with Unicode strings while adding new records to a sqlite database through the admin site.

```
class Translation(BaseModel):
  .....
  translation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When I try to insert a word like 'été' an error occurs:

```
**UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)**
```

Update: Added traceback: http://pastebin.com/yLYFNDGB

Comment: does this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392732/sqlite-python-unicode-and-non-utf-data help?

Comment: @AndrewCox: I believe that Django already takes care of all that, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/.

Comment: Please include the full traceback you get so we can pinpoint the exact cause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. Actually, the problem was not in Django or sqlite. The issue was with the **unicode**() method.

Previously it was:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return "{} ({})".format(self.translation, self.word.lang.abbr)
```

After an obvious fix, the problem is gone:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"{} ({})".format(self.translation, self.word.lang.abbr)
```

Comment: could you mark the question as answered? it's okay if you answered it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign **é** as a string to a variable, it actually takes it as **xe9**.

Like if you go to your python command line editor and write following code:

```
>>> a = u'café'
>>> a
```

and press enter, the **é** character is replaced by \xe9 as illustrated as follows:

```
>>> u'caf\xe9'
```

on the other hand, if you write this with print statement, you would get what you initially assigned, i.e:

```
>>> print a
café
```

So, after making this point, the solution to your problem is using **utf8 encoding** to get rid of **\xe9**. So you can encode your string in the following way:

```
>>> string_for_output = yourstring-with-é.encode('utf8', 'replace')
```

For more about this topic, you may consult [THIS URL](http://packages.python.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html) . It discusses your problem under the heading **"Frustration #3: Inconsistent treatment of output"**

Hope this helps.

Comment: My question is not about python+unicode, but about django+unicode.