# SQLAlchemy: dealing with CP-1252 data when Python is expecting it to be UTF-8

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am working with an existing SQLite database and experiencing errors due to the data being encoded in CP-1252, when Python is expecting it to be UTF-8.

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('dnd.sqlite')
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> result = curs.execute("SELECT * FROM dnd_characterclass WHERE id=802")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
OperationalError: Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'short_description_html'
with text ' <p>Over a dozen deities have worshipers who are paladins, 
promoting law and good across Faer�n, but it is the Weave itself that
```

The offending character is `\0xfb` which decodes to `û`. Other offending texts include `“?nd and slay illithids.”` which uses "smart quotes" `\0x93` and `\0x94`.

[SQLite, python, unicode, and non-utf data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392732/sqlite-python-unicode-and-non-utf-data) details how this problem can be solved when using `sqlite3` on its own.

**However, I am using SQLAlchemy.** How can I deal with CP-1252 encoded data in an SQLite database, when I am using SQLAlchemy?

---

Edit:

This would also apply for any other funny encodings in an SQLite `TEXT` field, like `latin-1`, `cp437`, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy and SQLite are behaving normally. The solution is to fix the non-UTF-8 data in the database.

I wrote the below, drawing inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395414/1191425 . It:

- loads up the target SQLite database
- lists all columns in all tables
- if the column is a `text`, `char`, or `clob` type - including variants like `varchar` and `longtext` - it re-encodes the data from the `INPUT_ENCODING` to UTF-8.

---

```
INPUT_ENCODING = 'cp1252' # The encoding you want to convert from
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('dnd_fixed.sqlite')
db.create_function('FIXENCODING', 1, lambda s: str(s).decode(INPUT_ENCODING))
cur = db.cursor()
tables = cur.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table"').fetchall()
tables = [t[0] for t in tables]
for table in tables:
    columns = cur.execute('PRAGMA table_info(%s)' % table ).fetchall() # Note: pragma arguments can't be parameterized.
    for column_id, column_name, column_type, nullable, default_value, primary_key in columns:
        if ('char' in column_type) or ('text' in column_type) or ('clob' in column_type):
            # Table names and column names can't be parameterized either.
            db.execute('UPDATE "{0}" SET "{1}" = FIXENCODING(CAST("{1}" AS BLOB))'.format(table, column_name))
```

---

After this script runs, all `*text*`, `*char*`, and `*clob*` fields are in UTF-8 and no more Unicode decoding errors will occur. I can now `Faerûn` to my heart's content.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a connection URI then you can add the following options to your DB connection URI:

```
DB_CONNECTION = mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{host}/{db_name}?{options}
DB_OPTIONS = {
    "charset": "cp-1252",
    "use_unicode": 1,
}
connection_uri = DB_CONNECTION.format(
    username=???,
    ...,
    options=urllib.urlencode(DB_OPTIONS)        
)
```

Assuming your SQLLite driver can handle those options (pymysql can, but I don't know 100% about sqllite), then your queries will return unicode strings.

Comment: Having a play at a console, and looking at the SQLAlchemy docs for the `sqlite` dialect, I don't think that the `sqlite` dialect supports the `charset` option.

Comment: You might be better off asking this question on the SQLAlchemy mailing list - the author is very active and helpful on it.

Comment: I ended up solving it by dropping down to the `sqlite3` module, and re-encoding the contents of all `TEXT` columns from `cp1252` to UTF-8.